# Floating point division vs floating point multiplication

Tags: c++, floating-point, micro-optimization

Is there any (non-microoptimization) performance gain by coding

```
float f1 = 200f / 2
```

in comparision to

```
float f2 = 200f * 0.5
```

A professor of mine told me a few years ago that floating point divisions were slower than floating point multiplications without elaborating the why.

Does this statement hold for modern PC architecture?

**Update1**

In respect to a comment, please do also consider this case:

```
float f1;
float f2 = 2
float f3 = 3;
for( i =0 ; i < 1e8; i++)
{
  f1 = (i * f2 + i / f3) * 0.5; //or divide by 2.0f, respectively
}
```

**Update 2**
Quoting from the comments:

> [I want] to know what are the algorithmic / architectural requirements that cause > division to be vastly more complicated in hardware than multiplication

Comment: The real way to find the answer is to try both and measure time.

Comment: Most compilers will optimise a literal constant expression such as this, so it makes no difference.

Comment: @sharptooth: Yes, trying out myself would solve the problem for my dev machine, but i thought if someone of the SO-crowd already has the answer for the general case, he'd like to share ;)

Comment: Paul is still correct; Most compilers will turn `/ 2.0` into `* 0.5`.

Comment: @Gabe, I think what Paul meant is that it would turn `200f / 2` into `100f`.

Comment: @mikerobi: They also change x / 2.f to x * 0.5f

Comment: @Paul: Such optimization is possible for powers of 2, but not in general. Aside from powers of two, no floating point number has a reciprocal that you can multiply by in place of the division.

Comment: Multiplication, in Sandy bridge can be broken to 5 steps (and hence 5 cycle latency)
1. Separate Mantissa and Exponents

Comment: I would +1, but I feel 87 (as it stands now) is somehow a perfect score for such a question :) Besides, divide by 2.0f and multiplying by 0.5 are not the same (amongst other things mentioned) in the sense that the latter _must_ propagate the operation to double, with possible performance implications. Even if the result would be the same for such unfortunately-round numbers (an example with 10 vs 0.1 would be more interesting).

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Yes, many CPUs can perform multiplication in 1 or 2 clock cycles but division always takes longer (although FP division is sometimes faster than integer division).

If you look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858483/how-can-i-compare-the-performance-of-log-and-fp-division-in-c) you will see that division can exceed 24 cycles.

Why does division take so much longer than multiplication? If you remember back to grade school, you may recall that multiplication can essentially be performed with many simultaneous additions. Division requires iterative subtraction that cannot be performed simultaneously so it takes longer. In fact, some FP units speed up division by performing a reciprocal approximation and multiplying by that. It isn't quite as accurate but is somewhat faster.

Comment: I think the OP wants to know what are the algorithmic / architectural requirements that cause division to be vastly more complicated in hardware than multiplication.

Comment: As I recall the Cray-1 didn't bother with a division instruction, it had a reciprocal instruction and expected you to multiply after that. For exactly this reason.

Comment: Mark: Indeed, the 4-step division algorithm is described on page 3-28 of the CRAY-1 Hardware Reference: reciprocal approximation, reciprocal iteration, numerator * approximation, half-precision quotient * correction factor.

Comment: @Gabe question, since every fp division can be converted to a multiplication, just make the exponent negative and multiply, why would division be any slower than multiplication

Comment: @aaronman: If FP numbers were stored as `x ^ y`, then multiplying by `x ^ -y` would be the same as division. However, FP numbers are stored as `x * 2^y`. Multiplying by `x * 2^-y` is just multiplication.

Comment: What's "grade school"?

Comment: Hardware designers are getting clever!!

Comment: @Pharap Elementary (or primary) school, apparently years 1-6 in the UK,

Answer (score 75):

Be very careful with division, and avoid it when possible.  For example, hoist `float inverse = 1.0f / divisor;` out of a loop and multiply by `inverse` inside the loop.  (If the rounding error in `inverse` is acceptable)

Usually `1.0/x` will not be exactly-representable as a `float` or `double`.  It will be exact when `x` is a power of 2.  This lets compilers optimize `x / 2.0f` to `x * 0.5f` without any change in the result.

To let the compiler do this optimization for you even when the result won't be exact (or with a runtime-variable divisor), you need options like  [`gcc -O3 -ffast-math`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html).  Specifically, `-freciprocal-math` (enabled by `-funsafe-math-optimizations` enabled by `-ffast-math`) lets the compiler replace `x / y` with `x * (1/y)` when that's useful.  Other compilers have similar options, and ICC may enable some "unsafe" optimization by default (I think it does, but I forget).

`-ffast-math` is often important to allow auto-vectorization of FP loops, especially reductions (e.g. summing an array into one scalar total), because FP math is not associative.  [Why doesn't GCC optimize a*a*a*a*a*a to (a*a*a)*(a*a*a)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430448/why-doesnt-gcc-optimize-aaaaaa-to-aaaaaa)

Also note that C++ compilers can fold `+` and `*` into an FMA in some cases (when compiling for a target that supports it, like `-march=haswell`), but they can't do that with `/`.

---

**Division has worse latency than multiplication or addition (or [FMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FMA_instruction_set)) by a factor of 2 to 4 on modern x86 CPUs, and worse throughput by a factor of 6 to 40<sup>1</sup>** (for a tight loop doing *only* division instead of *only* multiplication).

The divide / sqrt unit is not fully pipelined, for reasons explained in [@NathanWhitehead's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125033/floating-point-division-vs-floating-point-multiplication/5322101#5322101).  The worst ratios are for 256b vectors, because (unlike other execution units) the divide unit is usually not full-width, so wide vectors have to be done in two halves.  A not-fully-pipelined execution unit is so unusual that Intel CPUs have an `arith.divider_active` hardware performance counter to help you find code that bottlenecks on divider throughput instead of the usual front-end or execution port bottlenecks.  (Or more often, memory bottlenecks or long latency chains limiting instruction-level parallelism causing instruction throughput to be less than ~4 per clock).

**However, FP division and sqrt on Intel and AMD CPUs (other than KNL) is implemented as a single uop, so it doesn't necessarily have a big throughput impact on surrounding code**.  The best case for division is when out-of-order execution can hide the latency, and when there are lots of multiplies and adds (or other work)  that can happen in parallel with the divide.

(Integer division is microcoded as multiple uops on Intel, so it always has more impact on surrounding code that integer multiply.  There's less demand for high-performance integer division, so the hardware support isn't as fancy.  Related: [microcoded instructions like `idiv` can cause alignment-sensitive front-end bottlenecks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26907523/branch-alignment-for-loops-involving-micro-coded-instructions-on-intel-snb-famil).)

So for example, this will be really bad:

```
for ()
    a[i] = b[i] / scale;  // division throughput bottleneck

// Instead, use this:
float inv = 1.0 / scale;
for ()
    a[i] = b[i] * inv;  // multiply (or store) throughput bottleneck
```

All you're doing in the loop is load/divide/store, and they're independent so it's throughput that matters, not latency.

A reduction like `accumulator /= b[i]` would bottleneck on divide or multiply latency, rather than throughput.  But with multiple accumulators that you divide or multiply at the end, you can hide the latency and still saturate the throughput.  Note that `sum += a[i] / b[i]` bottlenecks on `add` latency or `div` throughput, but not `div` latency because the division isn't on the critical path (the loop-carried dependency chain).

---

**But in something like this ([approximating a function like `log(x)` with a ratio of two polynomials](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45787548/224132)), the divide can be pretty cheap**:

```
for () {
    // (not shown: extracting the exponent / mantissa)
    float p = polynomial(b[i], 1.23, -4.56, ...);  // FMA chain for a polynomial
    float q = polynomial(b[i], 3.21, -6.54, ...);
    a[i] = p/q;
}
```

For `log()` over the range of the mantissa, a ratio of two polynomials of order N has much less error than a single polynomial with 2N coefficients, and evaluating 2 in parallel gives you some instruction-level parallelism within a single loop body instead of one massively long dep chain, making things a LOT easier for out-of-order execution.

In this case, we don't bottleneck on divide latency because out-of-order execution can keep multiple iterations of the loop over the arrays in flight.

We don't bottleneck on divide *throughput* as long as our polynomials are big enough that we only have one divide for every 10 FMA instructions or so.  (And in a real `log()` use case, there's be a bunch of work extracting exponent / mantissa and combining things back together again, so there's even more work to do between divides.)

---

#### When you do need to divide, usually it's best to just divide instead of `rcpps`

x86 has an approximate-reciprocal instruction ([`rcpps`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/RCPPS.html)), which only gives you 12 bits of precision.  (AVX512F has 14 bits, and AVX512ER has 28 bits.)

You can use this to do `x / y = x * approx_recip(y)` without using an actual divide instruction.  (`rcpps` itsef is fairly fast; usually a bit slower than multiplication.  It uses a table lookup from a table internal to the CPU.  The divider hardware may use the same table for a starting point.)

For most purposes, `x * rcpps(y)` is too inaccurate, and a Newton-Raphson iteration to double the precision is required.  But that costs you [2 multiplies and 2 FMAs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31555260/fast-vectorized-rsqrt-and-reciprocal-with-sse-avx-depending-on-precision), and has latency about as high as an actual divide instruction.  If *all* you're doing is division, then it can be a throughput win.  (But you should avoid that kind of loop in the first place if you can, maybe by doing the division as part of another loop that does other work.)

But if you're using division as part of a more complex function, the `rcpps` itself + the extra mul + FMA usually makes it faster to just divide with a `divps` instruction, except on CPUs with very low `divps` throughput.

(For example Knight's Landing, see below.  KNL supports [AVX512ER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVX-512#New_instructions_in_AVX-512_exponential_and_reciprocal), so for `float` vectors the `VRCP28PS` result is already accurate enough to just multiply without a Newton-Raphson iteration.  `float` mantissa size is only 24 bits.)

---

#### Specific numbers from Agner Fog's tables:

Unlike every other ALU operation, division latency/throughput is data-dependent on some CPUs.  Again, this is because it's so slow and not fully pipelined.  Out-of-order scheduling is easier with fixed latencies, because it avoids write-back conflicts (when the same execution port tries to produce 2 results in the same cycle, e.g. from running a 3 cycle instruction and then two 1-cycle operations).

Generally, the fastest cases are when the divisor is a "round" number like `2.0` or `0.5` (i.e. the base2 `float` representation has lots of trailing zeros in the mantissa).

**`float`** **latency** (cycles) **/ throughput** (cycles per instruction, running just that back to back with independent inputs):

```
                   scalar & 128b vector        256b AVX vector
                   divss      |  mulss
                   divps xmm  |  mulps           vdivps ymm | vmulps ymm

Nehalem          7-14 /  7-14 | 5 / 1           (No AVX)
Sandybridge     10-14 / 10-14 | 5 / 1        21-29 / 20-28 (3 uops) | 5 / 1
Haswell         10-13 / 7     | 5 / 0.5       18-21 /   14 (3 uops) | 5 / 0.5
Skylake            11 / 3     | 4 / 0.5          11 /    5 (1 uop)  | 4 / 0.5

Piledriver       9-24 / 5-10  | 5-6 / 0.5      9-24 / 9-20 (2 uops) | 5-6 / 1 (2 uops)
Ryzen              10 / 3     | 3 / 0.5         10  /    6 (2 uops) | 3 / 1 (2 uops)

 Low-power CPUs:
Jaguar(scalar)     14 / 14    | 2 / 1
Jaguar             19 / 19    | 2 / 1            38 /   38 (2 uops) | 2 / 2 (2 uops)

Silvermont(scalar)    19 / 17    | 4 / 1
Silvermont      39 / 39 (6 uops) | 5 / 2            (No AVX)

KNL(scalar)     27 / 17 (3 uops) | 6 / 0.5
KNL             32 / 20 (18uops) | 6 / 0.5        32 / 32 (18 uops) | 6 / 0.5  (AVX and AVX512)
```

**`double`** **latency** (cycles) **/ throughput** (cycles per instruction):

```
                   scalar & 128b vector        256b AVX vector
                   divsd      |  mulsd
                   divpd xmm  |  mulpd           vdivpd ymm | vmulpd ymm

Nehalem         7-22 /  7-22 | 5 / 1        (No AVX)
Sandybridge    10-22 / 10-22 | 5 / 1        21-45 / 20-44 (3 uops) | 5 / 1
Haswell        10-20 /  8-14 | 5 / 0.5      19-35 / 16-28 (3 uops) | 5 / 0.5
Skylake        13-14 /     4 | 4 / 0.5      13-14 /     8 (1 uop)  | 4 / 0.5

Piledriver      9-27 /  5-10 | 5-6 / 1       9-27 / 9-18 (2 uops)  | 5-6 / 1 (2 uops)
Ryzen           8-13 /  4-5  | 4 / 0.5       8-13 /  8-9 (2 uops)  | 4 / 1 (2 uops)

  Low power CPUs:
Jaguar            19 /   19  | 4 / 2            38 /  38 (2 uops)  | 4 / 2 (2 uops)

Silvermont(scalar) 34 / 32    | 5 / 2
Silvermont         69 / 69 (6 uops) | 5 / 2           (No AVX)

KNL(scalar)      42 / 42 (3 uops) | 6 / 0.5   (Yes, Agner really lists scalar as slower than packed, but fewer uops)
KNL              32 / 20 (18uops) | 6 / 0.5        32 / 32 (18 uops) | 6 / 0.5  (AVX and AVX512)
```

Ivybridge and Broadwell are different too, but I wanted to keep the table small.  (Core2 (before Nehalem) has better divider performance, but its max clock speeds were lower.)

Atom, Silvermont, and **even Knight's Landing (Xeon Phi based on Silvermont) have exceptionally low divide performance**, and even a 128b vector is slower than scalar.  AMD's low-power Jaguar CPU (used in some consoles) is similar.  A high-performance divider takes a lot of die area.  Xeon Phi has low power *per-core*, and packing lots of cores on a die gives it tighter die-area constraints that Skylake-AVX512.  It seems that AVX512ER `rcp28ps` / `pd` is what you're "supposed" to use on KNL.

(See [this InstLatx64 result](https://github.com/InstLatx64/InstLatx64/blob/master/GenuineIntel0050654_SkylakeX_InstLatX64.txt) for Skylake-AVX512 aka Skylake-X.  Numbers for `vdivps zmm`: 18c / 10c, so half the throughput of `ymm`.)

---

Long latency chains become a problem when they're loop-carried, or when they're so long that they stop out-of-order execution from finding parallelism with other independent work.

---

**Footnote 1: how I made up those div vs. mul performance ratios:**

FP divide vs. multiple performance ratios are even worse than that in low-power CPUs like Silvermont and Jaguar, and even in Xeon Phi (KNL, where you should use AVX512ER).

**Actual divide/multiply throughput ratios for scalar (non-vectorized) `double`**: 8 on Ryzen and Skylake with their beefed-up dividers, but 16-28 on Haswell (data-dependent, and more likely towards the 28 cycle end unless your divisors are round numbers).  These modern CPUs have very powerful dividers, but their 2-per-clock multiply throughput blows it away.  (Even more so when your code can auto-vectorize with 256b AVX vectors).  Also note that with the right compiler options,
 those multiply throughputs also apply to FMA.

Numbers from http://agner.org/optimize/ instruction tables for Intel Haswell/Skylake and AMD Ryzen, for SSE scalar  (not including x87 `fmul` / `fdiv`) and for 256b AVX SIMD vectors of `float` or `double`.  See also the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki.

Comment: Update: https://uops.info/ have microbenchmark numbers with more detailed ports / uops breakdowns for multi-uop instructions than Agner Fog's tables do.  They're also fully machine-generated so no typos or other human errors, except possibly in designing the test for some instruction.  (I've only noticed that a once, for a couple instructions, where the numbers didn't make sense, and they fixed it after I let them know.)  For any instruction you can see what loop bodies they tested with.

Answer (score 23):

Division is inherently a much slower operation than multiplication.

And this may in fact be something that the compiler *cannot* (and you may not want to) optimize in many cases due to floating point inaccuracies. These two statements:

```
double d1 = 7 / 10.;
double d2 = 7 * 0.1;
```

are *not* semantically identical - `0.1` cannot be exactly represented as a `double`, so a slightly different value will end up being used - substituting the multiplication for the division in this case would yield a different result!

Comment: With g++, 200.f / 10 and 200.f * 0.1 emit exactly the same code.

Comment: @kotlinski: that makes g++ wrong, not my statement. I suppose one could argue that if the difference matters, you shouldn't be using floats in the first place, but it's definitely something I'd only do at the higher optimization levels if I were a compiler author.

Comment: @Michael: Wrong by which standard?

Comment: @kotlinski: wrong by the standard that a performance optmization done automatically by a compiler should never change the semantic behaviour of the code.

Comment: @Michael: I see no reason why it would calculate the wrong result in this case. I would wager the result is correct and the same in both expressions.

Comment: @kotlinski: then you don't understand how floating-point datatypes work. How much are you willing to wager?

Comment: -1, faulty logic. The underlying assumption here is that since 0.1f cannot be exactly represented, the compiler or the chip will pick a wildly different number. Of course it won't, it will pick a number that's very, very close to 0.1f - in fact, it will probably pick the best approximation. As a result, the result of `200f*0.1` will be very close to `20f`. And this number needs to be rounded, as `200f*0.1` cannot be exactly represented. Now, given that it is close to `20f`, guess what will it be rounded to?

Comment: @Michael: Please tell me, what would be correct value of f2, if not 0x41a00000?

Comment: @MSalters: the value that is closest to the result of the calculations that can be represented by a floating point number - and that is NOT necessarily 20f!

Comment: @kotlinski: The example may not have been chosen well, but try 7 / 10 vs. 7 * 0.1 using double precision...

Comment: you are correct, but for the wrong reasons. 7 / 10 instructs the compiler to perform an integer divison, so the result will be 0

Comment: @sum1stolemyname: that was not supposed to be code. Try it as double division and look at the resulting bit pattern.

Comment: if you try it, in a fair manner (that doesnt allow the compiler to optimize or substitute) you will find that 7 / 10 and 7 * 0.1 using double precision do not give the same result.  The multiply gives the wrong answer it gives a number greater than the divide.  floating point is about precision, if even a single bit is off it is wrong.  same goes for 7 / 5 != 7/0.2, but take a number you can represent 7 / 4 and 7 * 0.25, that will give the same result.  IEEE supports multiple rounding modes so you can overcome some of these problems (if you know the answer ahead of time).

Comment: note that the answer may not be accurate, which is okay for most, but not okay for everyone and worry about the real question.  why is the multiply faster...

Comment: Incidentally, in this case, multiply and divide are equally fast - they are calculated in compile-time.

Comment: Just in case people are wondering about this, I know VC++ allows you to configure if you want the compiler to make these optimizations. I'm assuming most modern C++ compilers give you similar options. See the MSDN page on the [/fp flag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7s85ffb.aspx).

Comment: First off, it needs to be 7.0 / 10.0 . But the real point is of practical nature. Any reasonable programming language tries best to deliver results closest to what the "normal" user without deep floating point knowledge would expect. Therefore good language semantics purposefully allow for higher precision at compile time so that constant multiplication and division are equal. Any reasonable programming language does not enforce a specific format for constant propagation but rounds only the final result to double precision (and probably does not require IEEE specifically). Due to usability.

Answer (score 11):

Yes. Every FPU I am aware of performs multiplications much faster than divisions.

However, modern PCs are *very* fast. They also contain pipelining archtectures that can make the difference negligable under many circumstances. To top it off, any decent compiler will perform the division operation you showed at *compile time* with optimizations turned on. For your updated example, any decent compiler would perform that transformation itself.

So generally **you should worry about making your code readable**, and let the compiler worry about making it fast. Only if you have a measured speed issue with that line should you worry about perverting your code for the sake of speed. Compilers are well aware of what is faster than what on their CPU's, and are generally much better optimizers than you can ever hope to be.

Comment: Making the code readable is not enough. Sometimes there are requirements to optimize something, and that would generally make the code hard to understand. Good developer would first write good unit tests, and then optimize the code. Readability is nice, but not always reachable goal.

Comment: @VJo - Either you missed my second to last sentence, or you disagree with my priorities. If its the latter, I'm afraid we are doomed to disagree.

Comment: Compilers are usually good in optimizing the code, but they have some limits. Would you believe it is possible to speed up some algorithm several times by some tricks? http://www.cortstratton.org/articles/OptimizingForSSE.php

Comment: doh posted by accident. Anyway, the code in that link is not readable, but is much faster then the readable original.

Comment: Compilers **cannot** optimize this for you. They are not allowed to because the results would be different and non-conformant (wrt IEEE-754). gcc provides a `-ffast-math` option for this purpose, but it breaks many things and cannot be used in general.

Comment: Bit of a necrocomment I suppose, but division typically isn't pipelined. So it can really make a huge dent in the performance. If anything, pipelining makes the difference in performance of multiplications and divisions even bigger, because one of pipelined but the other isn't.

Comment: C compilers _are allowed_ to optimize this because both division by 2.0 and multiplication by 0.5 are exact when using binary arithmetic, thus the result is the same. See section F.8.2 of the ISO C99 standard, which shows exactly this case as a permissible transformation when IEEE-754 bindings are used.

Answer (score 10):

Think about what is required for multiplication of two n bit numbers.  With the simplest method, you take one number x and repeatedly shift and conditionally add it to an accumulator (based on a bit in the other number y).  After n additions you are done.  Your result fits in 2n bits.

For division, you start with x of 2n bits and y of n bits, you want to compute x / y.  The simplest method is long division, but in binary.  At each stage you do a comparison and a subtraction to get one more bit of the quotient.  This takes you n steps.

Some differences: each step of the multiplication only needs to look at 1 bit; each stage of the division needs to look at n bits during the comparison.  Each stage of the multiplication is independent of all other stages (doesn't matter the order you add the partial products); for division each step depends on the previous step.  This is a big deal in hardware.  If things can be done independently then they can happen at the same time within a clock cycle.

Comment: Recent Intel CPUs (since Broadwell) [use a radix-1024 divider](http://www.anandtech.com/show/8355/intel-broadwell-architecture-preview/2) to get division done in fewer steps.  Unlike pretty much everything else, the divide unit is not fully pipelined (because as you say, lack of independence / parallelism is a big deal in hardware).  e.g. Skylake packed double-precision division (`vdivpd ymm`) has 16 times worse throughput than multiplication (`vmulpd ymm`), and it's worse in earlier CPUs with less powerful divide hardware.  http://agner.org/optimize/

Answer (score 2):

Newton rhapson solves integer division in O(M(n)) complexity via linear algebra apploximation. Faster than The otherwise O(n*n) complexity.

In code The method contains 10mults 9adds 2bitwiseshifts.

This explains why a division is roughly 12x as many cpu ticks as a multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the platform for which you are programming.

For example, doing lots of multiplication on an array on x86 should be much faster then doing division, because the compiler should create the assembler code which uses SIMD instructions. Since there are no division in the SIMD instructions, then you would see great improvements using multiplication then division.

Comment: But other answers are good as well. A division is generally slower or equal then multiplication, but it depends on the platform.

Comment: by now, there are [division instructions for SSE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826415/simd-sse-instruction-for-division-in-gcc)

Comment: `divps` is part of original SSE1, introduced in PentiumIII.  There is no SIMD *integer* division instruction, but SIMD FP division really exists.  The divide unit sometimes has even worse throughput / latency for wide vectors (esp. 256b AVX) than for scalar or 128b vectors.  Even Intel Skylake (with significantly faster FP division than Haswell/Broadwell) has `divps xmm` (4 packed floats): 11c latency, one per 3c throughput.  `divps ymm` (8 packed floats): 11c latency, one per 5c throughput.  (or for packed doubles: one per 4c or one per 8c)  See the [tag:x86] tag wiki for perf links.

Answer (score 0):

I got here looking at a divide by 2 as a special case as it is only required to subtract 1 from the exponent, and I'm optimising high-speed filtering code where the middle coefficient is .5.

If I had to do a lot of them in-place I might be tempted to create a lookup table using the upper 2 bytes of the `float` or `double` value and convert it with single lookup. Lookup tables were really useful when I was programming PDP-11s but with CPU caches they're less useful today although in some cases still quite worthwhile. In my current project I use them to convert an 8 bit `integer` to `float` and for lookups of a limited range of complex exponentials to do frequency translation.

Given that even with float the exponent spills over from the upper byte, requiring that the lookup table be 128kb, it might be a bit hard on the cache. The single-extended precision format could have the exponent just in the upper byte (at the expense of 1/2 the range), thus only requiring a 256-byte table. I'd put the operation in an inline function for clarity.

Clearly this is machine-dependent and still might not help. If it were not in place then the two halves (or quarter and 3/4 for single-extended precision) would each need at least one instruction. Note: in the above, when I say `upper`, I mean when looking at a big-endian representation.

Comment: Only worth considering in a case where SIMD won't work: multiplying a vector of 4 or 8 doubles or floats by a vector of `_mm256_set1_ps(0.5f)` only takes a single instruction on modern x86-64, AArch64, or PowerPC CPUs.  And usually with at least 1/clock throughput, so 4 to 16 multiplies per clock cycle depending on elements per vector and how many FP multiply pipes the CPU has.  Compared to loads, the widest CPUs can do at best 3 loads per clock cycle (even with SIMD gathers, which have a minimum element width of 4 bytes on x86-64.)

Comment: And yes you would need a LUT, since a simple integer subtract of `1 << 23` from a float bit-pattern would mangle `0.0f` (creating -Infinity).  Or an AND/compare (for exponent = all-ones or all-zero) / blend if you were using SIMD.  But that's slower than just multiplying by 0.5 on modern CPUs.  Maybe on a really low-end CPU, or without a hardware FPU at all?  But normally if FP performance is useful for a project, it'd think it would be more energy-efficient to pick a microcontroller with an FPU, or avoid floats (e.g. use fixed-point)

Comment: Agreed if useful at all it would be a unusual set of circumstances. As mentioned, LUTs have helped a lot for fixed->FP conversion and especially avoiding doing repetitive sin/cos operations. I've am blown away by the FP speed of modern processors. It's a great time to be alive.