# How to divide 16-bit integer by 255 with using SSE?

Tags: c++, image-processing, sse, simd, sse2

I deal with image processing.
I need to divide 16-bit integer SSE vector by 255.

I can't use shift operator like _mm_srli_epi16(), because 255 is not a multiple of power of 2.

I know of course that it is possible convert integer to float, perform division and then back conversion to integer.

But might somebody knows another solution...

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16822757/3959454) help?

Comment: Typically you would divide by 256 (with rounding rather than truncation) - is there some reason why it has to be 255 and not 256 ?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31575833/fastest-method-of-vectorized-integer-division-by-non-constant-divisor) question is interesting for you too. When you have to deal with non-constant integer division in future, conversion to float is a fast option as well.

Comment: @Paul-R If I will divide by 256 it cause decreasing of average brightness when this operation will be performed many times.

Comment: @Claudio: it's hard to say without seeing the rest of your code, but if you're working with the full 16 bit range and then scaling back down to 8 bits then the scale factor should be 256, otherwise if you take e.g. full scale uint16_t = 65535 and divide that by 255 you get 257. I guess you know what you're doing - I'm just puzzled...

Comment: Updated my answer with an unsigned version which has better throughput than the accepted answer.  I didn't realize before that you were using unsigned, but I think you are based on `srli` rather than `srai`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is an integer approximation of division by 255:

```
inline int DivideBy255(int value)
{
    return (value + 1 + (value >> 8)) >> 8;
}
```

So with using of SSE2 it will look like:

```
inline __m128i DivideI16By255(__m128i value)
{
    return _mm_srli_epi16(_mm_add_epi16(
        _mm_add_epi16(value, _mm_set1_epi16(1)), _mm_srli_epi16(value, 8)), 8);
}
```

For AVX2:

```
inline __m256i DivideI16By255(__m256i value)
{
    return _mm256_srli_epi16(_mm256_add_epi16(
        _mm256_add_epi16(value, _mm256_set1_epi16(1)), _mm256_srli_epi16(value, 8)), 8);
}
```

For Altivec (Power):

```
typedef __vector int16_t v128_s16;
const v128_s16 K16_0001 = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
const v128_s16 K16_0008 = {8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8};

inline v128_s16 DivideBy255(v128_s16 value)
{
    return vec_sr(vec_add(vec_add(value, K16_0001), vec_sr(value, K16_0008)), K16_0008);
}
```

For NEON (ARM):

```
inline int16x8_t DivideI16By255(int16x8_t value)
{
    return vshrq_n_s16(vaddq_s16(
        vaddq_s16(value, vdupq_n_s16(1)), vshrq_n_s16(value, 8)), 8);
}
```

Comment: This is wrong for `value == 65535` and for all negative numbers (so works neither for signed nor unsigned 16-bit integers)

Comment: I know that it perfectly works for alpha blending. But I don't exclude errors in another cases.

Comment: @AntonSavin: Accurate unsigned division by 255 is *more* efficient than this using `pmulhuw` for better throughput, although worse latency.  My answer from a couple years ago was only looking at signed, not unsigned.  (And for some reason, nobody seems to be distinguishing between the two, sometimes using `int` and sometimes using SIMD logical right shift.)

Answer (score 10):

If you want an exactly correct result for all cases, follow the advice from [Marc Glisse's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16822757/sse-integer-division#comment24256160_16822757) comment on the question Anton linked: [SSE integer division?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16822757/sse-integer-division)

Use GNU C native vector syntax to express division of a vector by your given scalar, [and see what it does on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Cimmintrin.h%3E%0A%0Aint+approxDivideBy255(int+value)+%7B%0A++++return+(value+%2B+1+%2B+(value+%3E%3E+8))+%3E%3E+8%3B%0A%7D%0Aunsigned+short+DivideBy255u(unsigned+short+value)+%7B%0A++++return+value+/+(short)255%3B%0A%7D%0Ashort+DivideBy255s(short+value)+%7B%0A++++return+value+/+(short)255%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Atypedef+short+vec_s16+__attribute__((vector_size(16)))%3B%0Avec_s16+div255(vec_s16+x)%7B+return+x/255%3B+%7D%0A%0A__m128i+div255_si128(__m128i+x)+%7B%0A++++__m128i+tmp+%3D+_mm_mulhi_epi16(x,+_mm_set1_epi16(0x8081))%3B%0A++++tmp+%3D+_mm_add_epi16(tmp,+x)%3B++//+There!'s+no+integer+FMA+that!'s+usable+here%0A++++x+++%3D+_mm_srai_epi16(x,+15)%3B++//+broadcast+the+sign+bit%0A++++tmp+%3D+_mm_srai_epi16(tmp,+7)%3B%0A++++return+_mm_sub_epi16(tmp,+x)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Atypedef+unsigned+short+vec_u16+__attribute__((vector_size(16)))%3B%0Avec_u16+divu255(vec_u16+x)%7B+return+x/255%3B+%7D%0A%0A%0A%0A//+gcc+seems+to+do+extra+mov+isns+to+software-pipeline+the+insert/extract%0Avec_s16+div_scalar(vec_s16+x,+short+++y)%7B+return+x/y%3B+%7D%0A%0A//+don!'t+even+think+of+using+this...%0Avec_s16+div_vector(vec_s16+x,+vec_s16+y)%7B+return+x/y%3B+%7D%0A%0A%0Aint+main()%7B%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g550,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-xc+-O3+-Wall+-fno-verbose-asm+-ffast-math+-mavx+-march%3Dhaswell',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+5.5+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4):

### Unsigned division is cheap:

```
typedef unsigned short vec_u16 __attribute__((vector_size(16)));
vec_u16 divu255(vec_u16 x){ return x/255; }  // unsigned division

#gcc5.5 -O3 -march=haswell
divu255:
    vpmulhuw        xmm0, xmm0, XMMWORD PTR .LC3[rip]  # _mm_set1_epi16(0x8081)
    vpsrlw          xmm0, xmm0, 7
    ret
```

Intrinsics version:

```
 // UNSIGNED division with intrinsics
__m128i div255_epu16(__m128i x) {
    __m128i mulhi = _mm_mulhi_epu16(x, _mm_set1_epi16(0x8081));
    return _mm_srli_epi16(mulhi, 7);
}
```

At only 2 uops, this has better throughput (but worse latency) than @ermlg's answer, if you're bottlenecked on front-end throughput, or port 0 throughput on Intel CPUs.  (As always, it depends on the surrounding code when you use this as part of a larger function.)  http://agner.org/optimize/

Vector shift only runs on port 0 on Intel chips, so @ermlg's 2 shifts + 1 add bottlenecks on port 0. (Again depending on surrounding code).  And it's 3 uops vs. 2 for this.

On Skylake, `pmulhuw` / `pmulhw` runs on ports 0 or 1, so it can run in parallel with a shift.  (But on Broadwell and earlier, they run only on port 0, conflicting with shifts.  So the only advantage on Intel pre-Skylake is fewer total uops for the front-end and for out-of-order execution to keep track of.)  `pmulhuw` has 5 cycle latency on Intel, vs. 1 for shifts, but OoO exec can typically hide a few cycles more latency when you can save uops for more throughput.

Ryzen also only runs pmulhuw on its P0, but shifts on P2, so it's excellent for this.

#### But *signed* integer division rounding semantics doesn't match shifts

```
typedef short vec_s16 __attribute__((vector_size(16)));

vec_s16 div255(vec_s16 x){ return x/255; }  // signed division

    ; function arg x starts in xmm0
    vpmulhw xmm1, xmm0, XMMWORD PTR .LC3[rip]  ; a vector of set1(0x8081)
    vpaddw  xmm1, xmm1, xmm0
    vpsraw  xmm0, xmm0, 15       ; 0 or -1 according to the sign bit of x
    vpsraw  xmm1, xmm1, 7        ; shift the mulhi-and-add result
    vpsubw  xmm0, xmm1, xmm0     ; result += (x<0)

.LC3:
        .value  -32639
        .value  -32639
        ; repeated
```

At the risk of bloating the answer, here it is again with intrinsics:

```
// SIGNED division
__m128i div255_epi16(__m128i x) {
    __m128i tmp = _mm_mulhi_epi16(x, _mm_set1_epi16(0x8081));
    tmp = _mm_add_epi16(tmp, x);  // There's no integer FMA that's usable here
    x   = _mm_srai_epi16(x, 15);  // broadcast the sign bit
    tmp = _mm_srai_epi16(tmp, 7);
    return _mm_sub_epi16(tmp, x);
}
```

In the godbolt output, note that gcc is smart enough to use the same 16B constant in memory for the `set1` and for the one it generated itself for `div255`.  AFAIK, this works like string-constant merging.

Answer (score 3):

GCC optimizes `x/255` with **x** is `unsigned short` to `DWORD(x * 0x8081) >> 0x17` which can further be simplified to `HWORD(x * 0x8081) >> 7` and finally `HWORD((x << 15) + (x << 7) + x) >> 7`.

SIMD macros can look like this:

```
#define MMX_DIV255_U16(x) _mm_srli_pi16(_mm_mulhi_pu16(x, _mm_set1_pi16((short)0x8081)), 7)
#define SSE2_DIV255_U16(x) _mm_srli_epi16(_mm_mulhi_epu16(x, _mm_set1_epi16((short)0x8081)), 7)
#define AVX2_DIV255_U16(x) _mm256_srli_epi16(_mm256_mulhi_epu16(x, _mm256_set1_epi16((short)0x8081)), 7)
```

Answer (score 3):

Accurate version:

```
#define div_255_fast(x)    (((x) + (((x) + 257) >> 8)) >> 8)
```

When x is in the range of [0, 65536], the ERROR is 0. It is twice as faster as `x/255`：

[image]

http://quick-bench.com/t3Y2-b4isYIwnKwMaPQi3n9dmtQ

SIMD version:

```
// (x + ((x + 257) >> 8)) >> 8
static inline __m128i _mm_fast_div_255_epu16(__m128i x) {
    return _mm_srli_epi16(_mm_adds_epu16(x, 
        _mm_srli_epi16(_mm_adds_epu16(x, _mm_set1_epi16(0x0101)), 8)), 8);
}
```

For a positive x above 65535, here is another version:

```
static inline int32_t fast_div_255_any (int32_t n) {
    uint64_t M = (((uint64_t)1) << 40) / 255 + 1;  // "1/255" in 24.40 fixed point number
    return (M * n) >> 40;   // fixed point multiply: n * (1/255)
}
```

More expansive (requires 64-bits mul), but still faster than `div` instruction.

Comment: What's `_const_simd_mask_8x0101`?  If that's a global variable, compilers typically do *worse* with that than with `_mm_set1_epi16(0x0101)`.

Comment: Also, I think you mean `[0, 65535]`, or `[0, 65536)`, because `65536` = 2^16 which doesn't fit in an epu16

Comment: @PeterCordes, updated and [0, 65536] is for the c version.

Comment: In plain C for scalar, you don't need special tricks.  Compilers already know how to use a multiplicative inverse: [Why does GCC use multiplication by a strange number in implementing integer division?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41183935).  Just use `unsigned` and you get efficient asm, or asm like your signed version that works for any `int32_t`: https://godbolt.org/z/cTzYzb.  Your `fast_div_255_any` appears to handle the sign bit so it actually works for any x, not just positive, right?  I guess it's a useful step in turning this into SIMD with `_mm_mul_epu32` (`pmuludq`)

Comment: @PeterCordes, div_255_fast is much cheaper than fast_div_255_any (which gcc may use). It is still faster than the compiler if your number is between 0 and 65536.

Comment: I only meant to comment on your `fast_div_255_any` which handles any `int32_t`.  But since you bring it up `div_255_fast` isn't *much* cheaper than normal `/255` for `uint32_t`, especially after inlining into a loop so it doesn't need so zero-extension is already done and the constant can be reused.   https://godbolt.org/z/HiNzD8 shows the stand-alone versions.  Modern x86 runs `imul r64, r64` as a single uop with 3 cycle latency, and it's just one `imul` and one `shr`, so a total critical path latency of 4 cycles.  vs. also 4 cycles and 4 uops instead of 2 for your `div_255_fast`.

Comment: It's significantly faster if you're compiling for Silvermont or Atom, though, where 64-bit `imul` is slow.  Or if you do something silly like use `int32_t x`  for `x/255` and force the compiler to handle signed division.

Comment: @PeterCordes `div_255_fast` is twice as faster as `x/255`, see the benchmark http://quick-bench.com/t3Y2-b4isYIwnKwMaPQi3n9dmtQ

Comment: I was talking about for scalar.  Your benchmark auto-vectorized both, with inefficient shuffling around `pmuludq` for the `x/255` version instead of just keeping 2 vector accumulators.  Sure, if that's what you're doing and you want to rely on auto-vectorization, then sure.  I guess most of the use-cases for division by 255 are for pixel data and tend to be data-parallel, but your answer labeled them as scalar vs. SIMD, not as auto-vectorization vs. manual vectorization.

Comment: And if you want auto-vectorization, the version in my answer using `unsigned short` works nicely and should be even more efficient if your data is actually packed 16-bit, not 32-bit elements with values in the 0..65535 range.  On some CPUs without as good hardware SIMD-integer multiply, your manually-vectorized version with saturating add might be good.

Answer (score 2):

Out of curiosity (and if performance is an issue), here is the accuracy of using
(val + offset) >> 8 as a substitute for (val / 255) for all 16 bit values up to 255*255 (for example when blending two 8bit values using an 8bit blend factor):

```
(avrg signed error / avrg abs error / max abs error)
offset    0:  0.49805 / 0.49805 / 1  (just shifting, no offset)
offset 0x7F:  0.00197 / 0.24806 / 1
offest 0x80: -0.00194 / 0.24806 / 1
```

All other offsets produce both larger signed and avrg errors. So if you can live with an average error of less than 0.25 than use offset+shifting for a small speed increase

```
// approximate division by 255 for packs of 8 times 16bit values in vals_packed
__m128i offset = _mm_set1_epi16(0x80); // constant
__m128i vals_packed_offest = _mm_add_epi16( vals_packed, offset );
__m128i result_packed = _mm_srli_epi16( vals_packed_offest , 8 );
```

Comment: With a saturating add, you could use this without disastrous results for values even closer to the wrap-around points.  `_mm_adds_epi16` or [`epu16`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/PADDUSB:PADDUSW.html) for signed/unsigned saturation.  Are you sure you want to use `srli` (logical right shift) instead of arithmetic right shift, `srai`?  Or are you doing this for unsigned?