# What is the avx instruction to divide two integer vectors of size 4?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, avx

I am trying to divide two __m128i variables. For that, I tried to use the avx intrinsic `_mm_div_epi32`, but the compiler complains that  '_mm_div_epi32' was not declared in this scope. I am using many other avx intrinsics as well in the code, and they work fine.

I am using gcc compiler version 5.4 and compile with the flag -mavx2. Also, I include the header file `immintrin.h`.

Comment: see [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42442325/how-to-divide-a-m256i-vector-by-an-integer-variable) but if you want to divide it to 32 bit you should not use `32768` use `2147483648` instead

Comment: I just checked you might not be able to use this method

Comment: Your two recent problem was mine too. I recommend you to review my questions it might be helpful.