# How to quickly divide a big uinteger into a word?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++20, biginteger, integer-division

I am currently developing a class to work with big unsigned integers. However, I need incomplete functionality, namely:

1. `bi_uint+=bi_uint` - Already implemented. No complaints.
2. `bi_uint*=std::uint_fast64_t` - Already implemented. No complaints.
3. `bi_uint/=std::uint_fast64_t` - Implemented but works very **slowly**, also requires a type that is twice as wide as `uint_fast64_t`. In the test case, division was *35* times slower than multiplication

Next, I will give my implementation of division, which is based on a simple long division algorithm:

```
#include <climits>
#include <cstdint>
#include <limits>
#include <vector>

class bi_uint
{
public:
    using u64_t = std::uint_fast64_t;
    constexpr static std::size_t u64_bits = CHAR_BIT * sizeof(u64_t);
    using u128_t = unsigned __int128;
    static_assert(sizeof(u128_t) >= sizeof(u64_t) * 2);

    //little-endian
    std::vector<u64_t> data;

    //User should guarantee data.size()>0 and val>0
    void self_div(const u64_t val)
    {
        auto it = data.rbegin();

        if(data.size() == 1) {
            *it /= val;
            return;
        }    
        
        u128_t rem = 0;
        if(*it < val) {
            rem = *it++;
            data.pop_back();
        }

        u128_t r = rem % val;
        while(it != data.rend()) {
            rem = (r << u64_bits) + *it;
            const u128_t q = rem / val;
            r = rem % val;
            *it++ = static_cast<u64_t>(q);
        }
    }
};
```

You can see that the `unsigned __int128` type was used, thefore, this option is not portable and is tied to a single compiler - GCC and also require x64 platform.

After reading the [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm) about division algorithms, I feel the appropriate algorithm would be "Newton-Raphson division". However, the "Newton–Raphson division" algorithm seems complicated to me. I guess there is a simpler algorithm for dividing the type "big_uint/uint" that would have almost the same performance.

**Q:** How to fast divide a `bi_uint` into a `u64_t`?

I have about 10^6 iterations, each iteration uses all the operations listed

If this is easily achievable, then I would like to have portability and not use `unsigned __int128`. Otherwise, I prefer to abandon portability in favor of an easier way.

**EDIT1:**
This is an academic project, I am not able to use third-party libraries.

Comment: `static_assert(sizeof(u128_t) >= sizeof(u64_t) * 2);` implies to me that you want `u64_t` to be `std::uint64_t` and not `std::uint_fast64_t` since the assert will fail if it the fast variant isn't exactly 64 bit.

Comment: Of possible interest: https://abseil.io/docs/cpp/guides/numeric

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I want to guarantee that the size of a variable of type u128_t is at least twice as large

Comment: @PavelDev The question is why you don't just use `std::uint64_t` which guarantees that? Any larger type fails the test.

Comment: @user1773252 Just read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500677/what-is-uint-fast32-t-and-why-should-it-be-used-instead-of-the-regular-int-and-u and "uint32_t is not guaranteed to exist."

Comment: @harold For this question, I specifically wrote a simplified version of the bi_uint class. In fact, the u64_t and u128_t types are set by the user in the class template. Obviously, this is a temporary solution and the u128_t type is only needed to support division. Although, the names are really poorly chosen. I meant that type u64_t has x bytes, then type u128_t should have 2x bytes

Comment: I recommend trying `std::vector<int>` to see if it's faster.

Comment: "division was 35 times slower than multiplication" What's the average size of the test data?

Comment: The linked page suggests Newton-Raphson as a fast algorithm for long division of multi-digits numbers, but I think that the posted function may use the [division by a constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm#Division_by_a_constant) algorithm, instead.

Comment: have you look at the generated code to ensure that div & mod divide is being done only once

Comment: you can try to [convert division to multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41183935/995714) by calculating the multiplicative inverse. Also try caching it, SIMD and other tricks in [libdivide](https://github.com/ridiculousfish/libdivide)

Comment: @pm100 I checked, in -O2 mode, only one udivmodti4 instruction is used, https://godbolt.org/z/6v6zGj7fx

Comment: @PavelDev If you already read [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71766513/941531) few days ago, then please read Part-2 of it, just added it right now. This part 2 implements from scratch all big interger and big float arithmetics, including your requested algorithms Newton-Raphson (square and cubic) and Goldschmidt. And shows all timings. This part 2 of my post wasn't present a day ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Part 1** (See Part 2 below)

I managed to speedup your division code **5x** times on my old laptop (and even **7.5x** times on GodBolt servers) using [Barrett Reduction](https://www.nayuki.io/page/barrett-reduction-algorithm), this is a technique that allows to replace single division by several multiplications and additions. Implemented whole code from sctracth just today.

If you want you can jump directly to code location at the end of my post, without reading long description, as code is fully runnable without any knowledge or dependency.

Code below is only for Intel x64, because I used Intel only [instructions](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html) and only 64-bit variants of them. Sure it can be re-written for x32 too and for other processors, because Barrett algorithm is generic.

To explain whole Barrett Reduction in short pseudo-code I'll write it in Python as it is simplest language suitable for understandable pseudo-code:

```py
# https://www.nayuki.io/page/barrett-reduction-algorithm

def BarrettR(n, s):
    return (1 << s) // n

def BarrettDivMod(x, n, r, s):
    q = (x * r) >> s
    t = x - q * n
    return (q, t) if t < n else (q + 1, t - n)
```

Basically in pseudo code above `BarrettR()` is done only single time for same divisor (you use same single-word divisor for whole big integer division). `BarrettDivMod()` is used each time when you want to make division or modulus operations, basically given input `x` and divisor `n` it returns tuple `(x / n, x % n)`, nothing else, but does it faster than regular division instruction.

In below C++ code I implement same two functions of Barrett, but do some C++ specific optimizations to make it even more faster. Optimizations are possible due to fact that divisor `n` is always 64-bit, `x` is 128-bit but higher half is always smaller than `n` (last assumption happens because higher half in your big integer division is always a remainder modulus `n`).

Barrett algorithm works with divisor `n` that is NOT a power of 2, so divisors like `0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, ...` are not allowed. This trivial case of divisor you can cover just by doing right bit-shift of big integer, because dividing by power of 2 is just a bit-shift. Any other divisor is allowed, including even divisors that are not power of 2.

Also it is important to note that my `BarrettDivMod()` accepts ONLY dividend `x` that is strictly smaller than `divisor * 2^64`, in other words higher half of 128-bit dividend `x` should be smaller than divisor. This is always true in your case of your big integer divison function, as higher half is always a remainder modulus divisor. This rule for `x` should be checked by you, it is checked in my `BarrettDivMod()` only as DEBUG assertion that is removed in release.

You can notice that `BarrettDivMod()` has two big branches, these are two variants of same algorithm, first uses CLang/GCC only type `unsigned __int128`, second uses only 64-bit instructions and hence suitable for MSVC.

I tried to target three compilers [CLang](https://clang.llvm.org/)/[GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/)/[MSVC](https://visualstudio.com/), but some how MSVC version got only 2x faster with Barrett, while CLang/GCC are 5x faster. Maybe I did some bug in MSVC code.

You can see that I used your class `bi_uint` for time measurement of two versions of code - with regular divide and with Barrett. **Important** to note that I changed your code quite significantly, first to not use `u128` (so that MSVC version compiles that has no u128), second not to modify `data` vector, so it does read only division and doesn't store final result (this read-only is needed for me to run speed tests very fast without copying `data` vector on each test iteration). So your code is broken in my snippet, it can't-be copy pasted to be used straight away, I only used your code for speed measurement.

Barrett reduction works faster not only because division is slower than multiplication, but also because multiplication and addition are both very well pipelined on moder CPUs, modern CPU can execute several mul or add instructions within one cycle, but only if these several mul/add don't depend on each other's result, in other words CPU can run several instructions in parallel within one cycle. As far as I know division can't be run in parallel, because there is only single module within CPU to make division, but still it is a bit pipelined, because after 50% of first division is done second division can be started in parallel at beginning of CPU pipeline.

On some computers you may notice that regular Divide version is much slower sometimes, this happens because CLang/GCC do fallback to library-based Soft implementation of Division even for 128 bit dividend. In this case my Barrett may show even `7-10x` times speedup, as it doesn't use library functions.

To overcome issue described above, about Soft division, it is better to add [Assembly code](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/asm) with usage of `DIV` instruction directly, or to find some Intrinsic function that implements this inside your compiler (I think CLang/GCC have such intrinsic). Also I can write this Assembly implementation if needed, just tell me in comments.

**Update**. As promised, implemented Assembly variant of 128 bit division for CLang/GCC, function `UDiv128Asm()`. After this change it is used as a main implementation for CLang/GCC 128 division instead of regular `u128(a) / b`. You may come back to regular u128 impementation by replacing `#if 0` with `#if 1` inside body of `UDiv128()` function.

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/vrs5d8o15)

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <bit>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

#include <immintrin.h>

#if defined(_MSC_VER) && !defined(__clang__)
    #define IS_MSVC 1
#else
    #define IS_MSVC 0
#endif

#if IS_MSVC
    #include <intrin.h>
#endif

#define ASSERT_MSG(cond, msg) { if (!(cond)) throw std::runtime_error("Assertion (" #cond ") failed at line " + std::to_string(__LINE__) + "! Msg: '" + std::string(msg) + "'."); }
#define ASSERT(cond) ASSERT_MSG(cond, "")
#ifdef _DEBUG
    #define DASSERT_MSG(cond, msg) ASSERT_MSG(cond, msg)
#else
    #define DASSERT_MSG(cond, msg)
#endif 
#define DASSERT(cond) DASSERT_MSG(cond, "")

using u16 = uint16_t;
using u32 = uint32_t;
using i64 = int64_t;
using u64 = uint64_t;
using UllPtr = unsigned long long *;

inline int GetExp(double x) {
    return int((std::bit_cast<uint64_t>(x) >> 52) & 0x7FF) - 1023;
}

inline size_t BitSizeWrong(uint64_t x) {
    return x == 0 ? 0 : (GetExp(x) + 1);
}

inline size_t BitSize(u64 x) {
    size_t r = 0;
    if (x >= (u64(1) << 32)) {
        x >>= 32;
        r += 32;
    }
    while (x >= 0x100) {
        x >>= 8;
        r += 8;
    }
    while (x) {
        x >>= 1;
        ++r;
    }
    return r;
}

#if !IS_MSVC
inline u64 UDiv128Asm(u64 h, u64 l, u64 d, u64 * r) {
    u64 q;
    asm (R"(
        .intel_syntax
        mov rdx, %V[h]
        mov rax, %V[l]
        div %V[d]
        mov %V[r], rdx
        mov %V[q], rax
    )"
        : [q] "=r" (q), [r] "=r" (*r)
        : [h] "r" (h), [l] "r" (l), [d] "r" (d)
        : "rax", "rdx"
    );
    return q;
}
#endif

inline std::pair<u64, u64> UDiv128(u64 hi, u64 lo, u64 d) {
    #if IS_MSVC
        u64 r, q = _udiv128(hi, lo, d, &r);
        return std::make_pair(q, r);
    #else
        #if 0
            using u128 = unsigned __int128;
            auto const dnd = (u128(hi) << 64) | lo;
            return std::make_pair(u64(dnd / d), u64(dnd % d));
        #else
            u64 r, q = UDiv128Asm(hi, lo, d, &r);
            return std::make_pair(q, r);
        #endif
    #endif
}

inline std::pair<u64, u64> UMul128(u64 a, u64 b) {
    #if IS_MSVC
        u64 hi, lo = _umul128(a, b, &hi);
        return std::make_pair(hi, lo);
    #else
        using u128 = unsigned __int128;
        auto const x = u128(a) * b;
        return std::make_pair(u64(x >> 64), u64(x));
    #endif
}

inline std::pair<u64, u64> USub128(u64 a_hi, u64 a_lo, u64 b_hi, u64 b_lo) {
    u64 r_hi, r_lo;
    _subborrow_u64(_subborrow_u64(0, a_lo, b_lo, (UllPtr)&r_lo), a_hi, b_hi, (UllPtr)&r_hi);
    return std::make_pair(r_hi, r_lo);
}

inline std::pair<u64, u64> UAdd128(u64 a_hi, u64 a_lo, u64 b_hi, u64 b_lo) {
    u64 r_hi, r_lo;
    _addcarry_u64(_addcarry_u64(0, a_lo, b_lo, (UllPtr)&r_lo), a_hi, b_hi, (UllPtr)&r_hi);
    return std::make_pair(r_hi, r_lo);
}

inline int UCmp128(u64 a_hi, u64 a_lo, u64 b_hi, u64 b_lo) {
    if (a_hi != b_hi)
        return a_hi < b_hi ? -1 : 1;
    return a_lo == b_lo ? 0 : a_lo < b_lo ? -1 : 1;
}

std::pair<u64, size_t> BarrettRS64(u64 n) {
    // https://www.nayuki.io/page/barrett-reduction-algorithm
    ASSERT_MSG(n >= 3 && (n & (n - 1)) != 0, "n " + std::to_string(n))
    size_t const nbits = BitSize(n);
    // 2^s = q * n + r;   2^s = (2^64 + q0) * n + r;  2^s - n * 2^64 = q0 * n + r
    u64 const dnd_hi = (nbits >= 64 ? 0ULL : (u64(1) << nbits)) - n;
    auto const q0 = UDiv128(dnd_hi, 0, n).first;
    return std::make_pair(q0, nbits);
}

template <bool Use128 = true, bool Adjust = true>
std::pair<u64, u64> BarrettDivMod64(u64 x_hi, u64 x_lo, u64 n, u64 r, size_t s) {
    // ((x_hi * 2^64 + x_lo) * (2^64 + r)) >> (64 + s)
    
    DASSERT(x_hi < n);
    
    #if !IS_MSVC
    if constexpr(Use128) {
        using u128 = unsigned __int128;
        u128 const xf = (u128(x_hi) << 64) | x_lo;
        u64 q = u64((u128(x_hi) * r + xf + u64((u128(x_lo) * r) >> 64)) >> s);
        if (s < 64) {
            u64 t = x_lo - q * n;
            if constexpr(Adjust) {
                u64 const mask = ~u64(i64(t - n) >> 63);
                q += mask & 1;
                t -= mask & n;
            }
            return std::make_pair(q, t);
        } else {
            u128 t = xf - u128(q) * n;
            return t < n ? std::make_pair(q, u64(t)) : std::make_pair(q + 1, u64(t) - n);
        }
    } else
    #endif
    {
        auto const w1a = UMul128(x_lo, r).first;
        auto const [w2b, w1b] = UMul128(x_hi, r);
        auto const w2c = x_hi, w1c = x_lo;
        u64 w1, w2 = _addcarry_u64(0, w1a, w1b, (UllPtr)&w1);
        w2 += _addcarry_u64(0, w1, w1c, (UllPtr)&w1);
        w2 += w2b + w2c;
        
        if (s < 64) {
            u64 q = (w2 << (64 - s)) | (w1 >> s);
            u64 t = x_lo - q * n;
            if constexpr(Adjust) {
                u64 const mask = ~u64(i64(t - n) >> 63);
                q += mask & 1;
                t -= mask & n;
            }
            return std::make_pair(q, t);
        } else {
            u64 const q = w2;
            auto const [b_hi, b_lo] = UMul128(q, n);
            auto const [t_hi, t_lo] = USub128(x_hi, x_lo, b_hi, b_lo);
            return t_hi != 0 || t_lo >= n ? std::make_pair(q + 1, t_lo - n) : std::make_pair(q, t_lo);
        }
    }
}

#include <random>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

void TestBarrett() {
    std::mt19937_64 rng{123}; //{std::random_device{}()};
    for (size_t i = 0; i < (1 << 11); ++i) {
        size_t const nbits = rng() % 63 + 2;
        u64 n = 0;
        do {
            n = (u64(1) << (nbits - 1)) + rng() % (u64(1) << (nbits - 1));
        } while (!(n >= 3 && (n & (n - 1)) != 0));
        auto const [br, bs] = BarrettRS64(n);
        for (size_t j = 0; j < (1 << 6); ++j) {
            u64 const hi = rng() % n, lo = rng();
            auto const [ref_q, ref_r] = UDiv128(hi, lo, n);
            u64 bar_q = 0, bar_r = 0;
            for (size_t k = 0; k < 2; ++k) {
                bar_q = 0; bar_r = 0;
                if (k == 0)
                    std::tie(bar_q, bar_r) = BarrettDivMod64<true>(hi, lo, n, br, bs);
                else
                    std::tie(bar_q, bar_r) = BarrettDivMod64<false>(hi, lo, n, br, bs);
                ASSERT_MSG(bar_q == ref_q && bar_r == ref_r, "i " + std::to_string(i) + ", j " + std::to_string(j) + ", k " + std::to_string(k) +
                    ", nbits " + std::to_string(nbits) + ", n " + std::to_string(n) + ", bar_q " + std::to_string(bar_q) +
                    ", ref_q " + std::to_string(ref_q) + ", bar_r " + std::to_string(bar_r) + ", ref_r " + std::to_string(ref_r));
            }
        }
    }
}

class bi_uint
{
public:
    using u64_t = std::uint64_t;
    constexpr static std::size_t u64_bits = 8 * sizeof(u64_t);

    //little-endian
    std::vector<u64_t> data;

    static auto constexpr DefPrep = [](auto n){
        return std::make_pair(false, false);
    };
    static auto constexpr DefDivMod = [](auto dnd_hi, auto dnd_lo, auto dsr, auto const & prep){
        return UDiv128(dnd_hi, dnd_lo, dsr);
    };
    
    //User should guarantee data.size()>0 and val>0
    template <typename PrepT = decltype(DefPrep), typename DivModT = decltype(DefDivMod)>
    void self_div(const u64_t val, PrepT const & Prep = DefPrep, DivModT const & DivMod = DefDivMod)
    {
        auto it = data.rbegin();

        if(data.size() == 1) {
            *it /= val;
            return;
        }    
        
        u64_t rem_hi = 0, rem_lo = 0;
        if(*it < val) {
            rem_lo = *it++;
            //data.pop_back();
        }
        
        auto const prep = Prep(val);
        
        u64_t r = rem_lo % val;
        u64_t q = 0;
        while(it != data.rend()) {
            rem_hi = r;
            rem_lo = *it;
            std::tie(q, r) = DivMod(rem_hi, rem_lo, val, prep);
            //*it++ = static_cast<u64_t>(q);
            it++;
            auto volatile out = static_cast<u64_t>(q);
        }
    }
};

void TestSpeed() {
    auto Time = []{
        static auto const gtb = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double>>(
            std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - gtb).count();
    };
    std::mt19937_64 rng{123};
    std::vector<u64> limbs, divisors;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < (1 << 17); ++i)
        limbs.push_back(rng());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < (1 << 8); ++i) {
        size_t const nbits = rng() % 63 + 2;
        u64 n = 0;
        do {
            n = (u64(1) << (nbits - 1)) + rng() % (u64(1) << (nbits - 1));
        } while (!(n >= 3 && (n & (n - 1)) != 0));
        divisors.push_back(n);
    }
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3);
    double div_time = 0;
    {
        bi_uint x;
        x.data = limbs;
        auto const tim = Time();
        for (auto dsr: divisors)
            x.self_div(dsr);
        div_time = Time() - tim;
        std::cout << "Divide time " << div_time << " sec" << std::endl;
    }
    {
        bi_uint x;
        x.data = limbs;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
            if (IS_MSVC && i == 0)
                continue;
            auto const tim = Time();
            for (auto dsr: divisors)
                x.self_div(dsr, [](auto n){ return BarrettRS64(n); },
                    [i](auto dnd_hi, auto dnd_lo, auto dsr, auto const & prep){
                        return i == 0 ? BarrettDivMod64<true>(dnd_hi, dnd_lo, dsr, prep.first, prep.second) :
                            BarrettDivMod64<false>(dnd_hi, dnd_lo, dsr, prep.first, prep.second);
                    });
            double const bar_time = Time() - tim;
            std::cout << "Barrett" << (i == 0 ? "128" : "64 ") << " time " << bar_time << " sec, boost " << div_time / bar_time << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    try {
        TestBarrett();
        TestSpeed();
        return 0;
    } catch (std::exception const & ex) {
        std::cout << "Exception: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Divide time 3.171 sec
Barrett128 time 0.675 sec, boost 4.695
Barrett64  time 0.642 sec, boost 4.937
```

---

**Part 2**

As you have a very interesting question, after few days when I first published this post, I decided to implement from scratch all big integer math.

Below code implements math operations `+, -, *, /, <<, >>` for natural big numbers (positive integers), and `+, -, *, /` for floating big numbers. Both types of numbers are of arbitrary size (even millions of bits). Besides those as you requested, I fully implemented [Newton-Raphson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm#Newton%E2%80%93Raphson_division) (both square and cubic variants) and [Goldschmidt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm#Goldschmidt_division) fast division algorithms.

Here is code snippet only for Newton-Raphson/Golschmidt functions, remaining code as it is very large is linked below on external server:

```cpp
BigFloat & DivNewtonRaphsonSquare(BigFloat b) {
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm#Newton%E2%80%93Raphson_division
    auto a = *this;
    a.exp_ += b.SetScale(0);
    if (b.sign_) {
        a.sign_ = !a.sign_;
        b.sign_ = false;
    }
    thread_local BigFloat two, c_48_17, c_32_17;
    thread_local size_t static_prec = 0;
    if (static_prec != BigFloat::prec_) {
        two = 2;
        c_48_17 = BigFloat(48) / BigFloat(17);
        c_32_17 = BigFloat(32) / BigFloat(17);
        static_prec = BigFloat::prec_;
    }
    BigFloat x = c_48_17 - c_32_17 * b;
    for (size_t i = 0, num_iters = std::ceil(std::log2(double(static_prec + 1)
            / std::log2(17.0))) + 0.1; i < num_iters; ++i)
        x = x * (two - b * x);
    *this = a * x;
    return BitNorm();
}
BigFloat & DivNewtonRaphsonCubic(BigFloat b) {
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm#Newton%E2%80%93Raphson_division
    auto a = *this;
    a.exp_ += b.SetScale(0);
    if (b.sign_) {
        a.sign_ = !a.sign_;
        b.sign_ = false;
    }
    thread_local BigFloat one, c_140_33, c_m64_11, c_256_99;
    thread_local size_t static_prec = 0;
    if (static_prec != BigFloat::prec_) {
        one = 1;
        c_140_33 = BigFloat(140) / BigFloat(33);
        c_m64_11 = BigFloat(-64) / BigFloat(11);
        c_256_99 = BigFloat(256) / BigFloat(99);
        static_prec = BigFloat::prec_;
    }
    BigFloat e, y, x = c_140_33 + b * (c_m64_11 + b * c_256_99);
    for (size_t i = 0, num_iters = std::ceil(std::log2(double(static_prec + 1)
            / std::log2(99.0)) / std::log2(3.0)) + 0.1; i < num_iters; ++i) {
        e = one - b * x;
        y = x * e;
        x = x + y + y * e;
    }
    *this = a * x;
    return BitNorm();
}
BigFloat & DivGoldschmidt(BigFloat b) {
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm#Goldschmidt_division
    auto a = *this;
    a.exp_ += b.SetScale(0);
    if (b.sign_) {
        a.sign_ = !a.sign_;
        b.sign_ = false;
    }
    BigFloat one = 1, two = 2, f;
    for (size_t i = 0;; ++i) {
        f = two - b;
        a *= f;
        b *= f;
        if (i % 3 == 0 && (one - b).GetScale() < -i64(prec_) + i64(bit_sizeof(Word)))
            break;
    }
    *this = a;
    return BitNorm();
}
```

See `Output:` below, it will show that Newton-Raphson and Goldschmidt methods are actually **10x** times slower than regular School-grade (called `Reference` in output) algorithm. Between each other these 3 advanced algorithms are about same speed. Probably Raphson/Goldschmidt could be faster if to use [Fast Fourier Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sch%C3%B6nhage%E2%80%93Strassen_algorithm) for multiplication, because multiplication of two large numbers takes 95% of time of these algorithms. In code below all results of Raphson/Goldschmidt algorithms are not only time-measured but also checked for correctness of results compared to School-grade (Reference) algorithm (see `diff 2^...` in console output, this shows how large is difference of result compared to school grade).

**FULL SOURCE CODE HERE**. Full code is so huge that it didn't fit into this StackOverflow due to SO limit of 30 000 characters per post, although I wrote this code from scracth specifically for this post. That's why providing [external download link](https://pastebin.com/raw/t2ePejx6) (PasteBin server), also click `Try it online!` linke below, it is same copy of code that is run live on GodBolt's linux servers:

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/n7YbGz7h4)

Output:

```
==========     1 K bits   ==========
Reference    0.000029 sec
Raphson2     0.000066 sec, boost 0.440x, diff 2^-8192
Raphson3     0.000092 sec, boost 0.317x, diff 2^-8192
Goldschmidt  0.000080 sec, boost 0.365x, diff 2^-1022

==========     2 K bits   ==========
Reference    0.000071 sec
Raphson2     0.000177 sec, boost 0.400x, diff 2^-16384
Raphson3     0.000283 sec, boost 0.250x, diff 2^-16384
Goldschmidt  0.000388 sec, boost 0.182x, diff 2^-2046

==========     4 K bits   ==========
Reference    0.000319 sec
Raphson2     0.000875 sec, boost 0.365x, diff 2^-4094
Raphson3     0.001122 sec, boost 0.285x, diff 2^-32768
Goldschmidt  0.000881 sec, boost 0.362x, diff 2^-32768

==========     8 K bits   ==========
Reference    0.000484 sec
Raphson2     0.002281 sec, boost 0.212x, diff 2^-65536
Raphson3     0.002341 sec, boost 0.207x, diff 2^-65536
Goldschmidt  0.002432 sec, boost 0.199x, diff 2^-8189

==========    16 K bits   ==========
Reference    0.001199 sec
Raphson2     0.009042 sec, boost 0.133x, diff 2^-16382
Raphson3     0.009519 sec, boost 0.126x, diff 2^-131072
Goldschmidt  0.009047 sec, boost 0.133x, diff 2^-16380

==========    32 K bits   ==========
Reference    0.004311 sec
Raphson2     0.039151 sec, boost 0.110x, diff 2^-32766
Raphson3     0.041058 sec, boost 0.105x, diff 2^-262144
Goldschmidt  0.045517 sec, boost 0.095x, diff 2^-32764

==========    64 K bits   ==========
Reference    0.016273 sec
Raphson2     0.165656 sec, boost 0.098x, diff 2^-524288
Raphson3     0.210301 sec, boost 0.077x, diff 2^-65535
Goldschmidt  0.208081 sec, boost 0.078x, diff 2^-65534

==========   128 K bits   ==========
Reference    0.059469 sec
Raphson2     0.725865 sec, boost 0.082x, diff 2^-1048576
Raphson3     0.735530 sec, boost 0.081x, diff 2^-1048576
Goldschmidt  0.703991 sec, boost 0.084x, diff 2^-131069

==========   256 K bits   ==========
Reference    0.326368 sec
Raphson2     3.007454 sec, boost 0.109x, diff 2^-2097152
Raphson3     2.977631 sec, boost 0.110x, diff 2^-2097152
Goldschmidt  3.363632 sec, boost 0.097x, diff 2^-262141

==========   512 K bits   ==========
Reference    1.138663 sec
Raphson2    12.827783 sec, boost 0.089x, diff 2^-524287
Raphson3    13.799401 sec, boost 0.083x, diff 2^-524287
Goldschmidt 15.836072 sec, boost 0.072x, diff 2^-524286
```

Comment: Thank you, that's a great answer. It will take me some time to figure this out. However, I think it is correct and I will accept it in absentia.

Comment: @PavelDev As you can see Part-1 of my answer has Barrett Reduction speedup of your code, 7.5x times speedup, it speeds up only division of long integer by single word. Part-2 on contrary is focused on ALL the arithmetics of big integers and big floats, specifically for your question in last two day I implemented from scratch ALL arithmetics of big integers and big floats of any precision (millions of bits too). Both big integers and floats have operations `+, -, *, /` which are classical school-grade algorithms. Floats also have Newton-Raphson (square, cubic), Goldschmidt, you asked for them.

Comment: @PavelDev Newton-Raphson and Goldschmidt appeared to be **10x** times Slower than regular school algorithm of long division. And tomorrow I'm planning to improve speed of this school division even more. First I may use Barrett Reduction, but it will not give much speedup because `DIV` instruction there takes about 5-10% of time, when divisor is not a single word but multi-word, in this case most of time is spent in multiplication and subtraction. Another speedup that I'm planning to do is to implement Divide and Conquer approach, I want to make recursive variant of school algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

On most of the modern CPUs, division is indeed much slower than multiplication.

Referring to

https://agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf

That on Intel Skylake an MUL/IMUL has a latency of 3-4 cycles; while an DIV/IDIV could take 26-90 cycles; which is 7 - 23 times slower than MUL; so your initial benchmark result isn't really a surprise.

If you happen to be on x86 CPU, as showing in the answer below, if this is indeed the bottleneck you could try to utilize AVX/SSE instructions. Basically you'd need to rely on special instructions than a general one like DIV/IDIV.

[How to divide a __m256i vector by an integer variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42442325/how-to-divide-a-m256i-vector-by-an-integer-variable)