# Why is F# so much slower than C#? (prime number benchmark)

Tags: c#, f#, benchmarking, primes

I thought that F# was meant to be faster than C#, I made a probably bad benchmark tool and C# got 16239ms while F# did way worse at 49583ms. Could somebody explain why this is? I'm considering leaving F# and going back to C#. Is it possible to get the same result in F# with way faster code?

Here is the code I used, I made it as equal as I possibly could.

F# (49583ms)

```
open System
open System.Diagnostics

let stopwatch = new Stopwatch()
stopwatch.Start()

let mutable isPrime = true

for i in 2 .. 100000 do
    for j in 2 .. i do
        if i <> j && i % j = 0 then
            isPrime <- false
    if isPrime then
        printfn "%i" i
    isPrime <- true

stopwatch.Stop()
printfn "Elapsed time: %ims" stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds

Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
```

C# (16239ms)

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();

            bool isPrime = true;

            for (int i = 2; i <= 100000; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 2; j <= i; j++)
                {
                    if (i != j && i % j == 0)
                    {
                        isPrime = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (isPrime)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(i);
                }
                isPrime = true;
            }
            stopwatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Elapsed time: " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you running the code?  Are you running the F# code in Interactive and the C# code as a console app?

Comment: Why should it matter if F# or C# (or VB.NET), wont they all compile to the same CIL and should be 100% the same at the end?

Comment: Your C# code breaks out of the inner loop, the F# doesn't.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the linked question. The issue in the linked question was enumerators, while the issue here is the absence of a `break` equivalent in the F# code. I was halfway through writing an answer when the question was incorrectly closed as a dupe.

Comment: I agree it is not a duplicate.

Comment: Sorry, I felt pressured so I accepted it as a duplicate, I would love to see an answer! @rmunn

Comment: While we're waiting for it to re-open, you can play with this:  `{2 .. 100000} |> Seq.filter (fun i -> {2 .. i-1} |> Seq.forall (fun j -> i % j <> 0)) |> Seq.iter (printfn "%i")`.  This is more idiomatic F# for the same logic, and it runs in about 3 seconds for me in F# Interactive.

Comment: @rmunn: it's reopened now, if you can recover or recreate what you wrote.

Comment: @PeterCordes - I refreshed the page and SO had saved what I had written so far, which is nice. I'm working on the rest of the answer now (basically taking Aaron Eshbach's suggestion and explaining it step-by-step).

Comment: @Alanay - One improvement you can make to this code (which I didn't mention in the answer because it's irrelevant to the question) would be to only check divisors up to (and including) the square root of the number. So if you're checking whether 42 is prime, you need to check up to 6 but you don't have to check 7, because 6 < sqrt(42) < 7. To add this in F#, add a `Seq.filter` call just before the `Seq.foreach`, like `{2 .. i-1} |> Seq.filter (fun j -> j * j <= i) |> Seq.forall (fun j -> i % j <> 0)`

Comment: @rmunn I was going to mention the square-root optimization as well.  I used `{2 .. Math.Sqrt(float i) |> int}` and it ran in just 71ms (> 40x faster).

Comment: @AaronM.Eshbach And that's with floating-point square root, which is WAY slower than multiplying the int by itself. What speed do you get with the `|> Seq.filter (fun j -> j * j <= i)` approach? I'd bet it's even faster than 71ms... But I'd like to know. And I can't just run that on my machine, because my results may not be comparable to yours due to different CPUs, clock speeds, RAM, and all sorts of potential factors.

Comment: @rmunn, with `Seq.filter` it gets much slower (about 8 seconds), because it still has to iterate through all the numbers from 2 to i instead of 2 to the sqrt(i).  Using `Seq.takeWhile` instead of `Seq.filter` takes it down to 150ms, but still doesn't seem to be as fast as `{2.. Math.Sqrt(i)}`.

Comment: 730 milliseconds on 2X Quadro K420 with 384 total CUDA cores. Same code, just outermost loop is parallelized. This is C++ based so I guess C++ is fastest.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik I don't know about that.  I can get it down to 561ms using F# `Async.Parallel` as well (without using the sqrt optimization), and that's just using the CPU in my Surface.  An F# CUDA library like [Alea.Cubase](http://www.aleagpu.com/release/3_0_4/doc/gpu_programming_fsharp.html) could also be used.

Comment: I don't think anyone claimed F# is way faster. Perhaps easier to write parallel code in and therefore easier to exploit multiple cores. Also, `Seq` and performance seldomly mix well.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The F# program is slower because your programs are not equivalent. Your C# code has a `break` statement in the inner `for` loop, but your F# program does not. Thus, for every even number, the C# code will stop after checking for divisibility by 2, while the F# program will check every number from 2 to `i`. With such a large difference in work done, it's actually surprising that the F# code is *only* three times slower!

Now, F# deliberately does not have a `break` statement, so you can't quite translate the C# code directly to F#. But you can use functions that include short-circuiting logic. For example, in the comments, Aaron M. Eshbach suggested the following:

```
{2 .. 100000}
|> Seq.filter (fun i -> {2 .. i-1} |> Seq.forall (fun j -> i % j <> 0))
|> Seq.iter (printfn "%i")
```

This uses `Seq.forall`, which does do short-circuiting: it will check each input in the sequence against the condition, and if the condition ever returns `false`, it will stop and make no more checks. (Because functions in the `Seq` module are **lazy** and will do no more work than absolutely required to get their output). This is like having a `break` in your C# code.

I'll go through this step by step so you can see how it works:

```
{2 .. 100000}
```

This creates a lazy sequence of ints that starts at 2 and goes up to (and including) 100000.

```
|> Seq.filter (fun i -> (some expression involving i))
```

I've broken the next line into two sections: the outer `Seq.filter` part, and the inner expression involving `i`. The `Seq.filter` part takes the sequence and filters it: for every item in the sequence, call it `i` and evaluate the expression. If that expression evaluates to `true`, then keep the item and pass it through to the next step in the chain. If the expression is `false`, then throw that item away.

Now, the expression involving `i` is:

```
{2 .. i-1} |> Seq.forall (fun j -> i % j <> 0)
```

This first constructs a lazy sequence that starts at 2 and goes up to `i` minus one, inclusive. (Or you could think of it as starting at 2 and going up to `i`, but not including `i`). It then checks whether *every* item of that sequence fulfills a certain condition (that's the `Seq.forall` function). And, as an implementation detail of `Seq.forall`, because it's lazy and does no more work than it absolutely has to, the minute it finds a `false` result it will stop and not go through the input sequence any longer. (Because once you find a single counter-example, it is no longer possible for the `forall` function to return true, so it stops as soon as its result is known.) And what is the expression being checked in `Seq.forall`? It's `fun j -> i % j <> 0`. So `j` is the inner loop variable, `i` is the outer variable (the one assigned in the `Seq.filter` part), and the logic is just the same as your C# loops.

Now, remember that we're inside a `Seq.filter` here. So if the `Seq.forall` returns true, then `Seq.filter` will keep the value of `i`. But if `Seq.forall` returns false, then `Seq.filter` will discard this value of `i` from passing through to the next step.

Finally, we have this line as the next (and final) step:

```
|> Seq.iter (printfn "%i")
```

What this does is pretty much exactly the same as:

```
for number in inputSoFar do
    printfn "%i" number
```

The `(printfn "%i")` call might look unusual to you if you're new to F#. This is [currying](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/currying/), and it's a very useful concept and one that it's important to get used to. So spend some time thinking about this: in F#, the following two lines of code are *completely equivalent*:

```
(fun y -> someFunctionCall x y)
(someFunctionCall x)
```

So `fun item -> printfn "%i" item` can always be replaced by `printfn "%i`. And `Seq.iter` is the equivalent of a `for` loop:

```
inputSoFar |> Seq.iter (someFunctionCall x)
```

is exactly equivalent to:

```
for item in inputSoFar do
    someFunctionCall x item
```

So there you have it: why your F# program is slower, and also how to write an F# program that will follow the same logic as the C# one, but will have the equivalent of a `break` statement in it.

Comment: BTW, if you replace `Seq.iter` with `Seq.map` at the end, you'll discover that the code *does not print anything*. That's because `Seq.iter` is a *non-lazy* function (I prefer the term "an *eager* function" but you may or may not have encountered that term before): it is guaranteed to go through all of its input and perform an operation on each one. Whereas `Seq.map` is *lazy*: it sets up a mapping to perform on every item it receives, but it won't actually do any work yet until it has to. (Usually because someone called an *eager* function like `Seq.iter`, or `Seq.toList`, down the chain).

Comment: Thanks so much this helps a lot, I want to learn more about sequence and list functions but there aren't many examples out there.

Comment: @Alanay - Best way to learn about F#'s list functions (and sequence functions too, they have basically the same API) is Scott Wlaschin's **excellent** site: https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/list-module-functions/

Answer (score 7):

I know there's an already accepted answer, but just wanted to add this.

Done a lot of C# over the years, but not much F#. The following would be more equivalent to the C# code.

```
open System
open System.Diagnostics

let stopwatch = new Stopwatch()
stopwatch.Start()

let mutable loop = true

for i in 2 .. 100000 do
    let mutable j = 2
    while loop do
        if i <> j && i % j = 0 then
            loop <- false
        else
            j <- j + 1
            if j >= i then
                printfn "%i" i
                loop <- false
    loop <- true

stopwatch.Stop()
printfn "Elapsed time: %ims" stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds
```

And in my tests on LinqPad, the above is faster than the solution suggested by Aaron M. Eshbach.

It also comes out with surprisingly similar IL.

Comment: No idea how that it is faster but great job, thanks for posting this! I'm going to read these all more thoroughly soon.

Comment: This will be marginally faster because it eliminates the overhead of the calls to the `Seq.filter`, `Seq.forall`, and `Seq.iter` functions.  With hundreds of thousands or millions of iterations, even the tiny overhead of a couple function calls can add up.  I would still do it with the sequence-processing functions, because the meaning is clearer and the code is more idiomatic.

Comment: @AaronM.Eshbach in my LinqPad tests it was a lot faster. I agree that my code isn't in the spirit of F# though. Was just posting for illustrative purposes.

Answer (score 6):

As other mentioned the code is not doing the same thing and you need to employ techniques to ensure that the inner loop is stopped after a prime is found.

In addition, you are printing values to standard out. This is usually not desired when you are doing CPU performance tests as a significant amount of time might be I/O skewing the results of the tests.

Anyway, even though there is an accepted answer I decided to tinker a bit with this as well to see compare the different proposed solutions with some of my own.

The performance run is in `x64` mode on .NET 4.7.1.

I compared the different proposed F# solutions plus some of my own variants:

```
Running 'Original(F#)' with 100000 (10512)...
  ... it took 14533 ms with (0, 0, 0) cc and produces 9592 GOOD primes
Running 'Original(C#)' with 100000 (10512)...
  ... it took 1343 ms with (0, 0, 0) cc and produces 9592 GOOD primes
Running 'Aaron' with 100000 (10512)...
  ... it took 5027 ms with (3, 1, 0) cc and produces 9592 GOOD primes
Running 'SteveJ' with 100000 (10512)...
  ... it took 1640 ms with (0, 0, 0) cc and produces 9592 GOOD primes
Running 'Dumetrulo1' with 100000 (10512)...
  ... it took 1908 ms with (0, 0, 0) cc and produces 9592 GOOD primes
Running 'Dumetrulo2' with 100000 (10512)...
  ... it took 970 ms with (0, 0, 0) cc and produces 9592 GOOD primes
Running 'Simple' with 100000 (10512)...
  ... it took 621 ms with (0, 0, 0) cc and produces 9592 GOOD primes
Running 'PushStream' with 100000 (10512)...
  ... it took 1627 ms with (0, 0, 0) cc and produces 9592 GOOD primes
Running 'Unstalling' with 100000 (10512)...
  ... it took 551 ms with (0, 0, 0) cc and produces 9592 GOOD primes
Running 'Vectors' with 100000 (10512)...
  ... it took 1076 ms with (0, 0, 0) cc and produces 9592 GOOD primes
Running 'VectorsUnstalling' with 100000 (10512)...
  ... it took 1072 ms with (0, 0, 0) cc and produces 9592 GOOD primes
Running 'BestAttempt' with 100000 (10512)...
  ... it took 4 ms with (0, 0, 0) cc and produces 9592 GOOD primes
```

1. `Original(F#)` - The original F# code by OP changed to not use stdout
2. `Original(C#)` - The original C# code by OP changed to not use stdout
3. `Aaron` - The idiomatic approach using `Seq`. As expected `Seq` and performance usually don't go well together.
4. `SteveJ` - @SteveJ tried to mimic the C# code in F#
5. `Dumetrulo1` - @dumetrulo implemented the algorithm in tail recursion
6. `Dumetrulo2` - @dumetrulo improved the algorithm by stepping +2 instead of +1 (don't need to check even numbers).
7. `Simple` - My attempt to use a similar approach to `Dumetrulo2` with tail recursion.
8. `PushStream` - My attempt to use a simplistic push stream (`Seq` is a pull stream)
9. `Unstalling` - My attempt to try to unstall the CPU in case the instructions used have latency
10. `Vectors` - My attempt using `System.Numerics.Vectors` to do multiple divisions per operation (aka SIMD). Unfortunately the vectors libary don't support `mod` so I had to emulate it.
11. `VectorsUnstalling` - My attempt to improve `Vectors` by trying to unstall the CPU.
12. `BestAttempt` - Like `Simple` but only checks numbers up to `sqrt n` when determining if is prime.

**Wrapping up**

1. F# loops don't have `continue` nor `break`. Tail-recursion in F# is IMO a better way to implement loops that need to `break`.
2. When comparing performance of languages should one compare the best possible performance or compare performance of idiomatic solutions? I personally think the best possible performance is the right way to go but I know people disagree with me (I wrote a [mandelbrot version for benchmark the game](https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/performance/mandelbrot.html) for F# with comparable performance to C but it wasn't accepted because the style was seen as non-idiomatic for F#).
3. `Seq` in F# unfortunately adds significant overhead. I have a hard time bringing myself to use it even when the overhead is not relevant.
4. Modern CPUs instructions have different numbers for throughput and latency. This means that sometimes in order to speed up performance one need to process multiple independent samples in the inner loop to allow the out of order execution unit to reorder the program to hide the latency. If your CPU has hyper threading and you run the algorithm on multiple threads hyper threading can mitigate the latency "automatically".
5. The lack of `mod` of vectors prevented the attempt to use SIMD to gain any performance over the non SIMD solution.
6. If I modify `Unstalling` attempt to loop the same number of times as the C# code the final result is `1100 ms` in F# compared to `1343 ms` in C#. So F# can be made to run very much comparable to C#. If one apply a few more tricks it only takes `4 ms` but it would be the same for C#  as well. Anyway, pretty decent to go from almost `15 sec` to `4 ms`.

Hope it was interesting to someone

Full source code:

```
module Common = 
  open System
  open System.Diagnostics

  let now =
    let sw = Stopwatch ()
    sw.Start ()
    fun () -> sw.ElapsedMilliseconds

  let time i a =
    let inline cc i       = GC.CollectionCount i

    let ii = i ()

    GC.Collect (2, GCCollectionMode.Forced, true)

    let bcc0, bcc1, bcc2  = cc 0, cc 1, cc 2
    let b                 = now ()

    let v = a ii

    let e = now ()
    let ecc0, ecc1, ecc2  = cc 0, cc 1, cc 2

    v, (e - b), ecc0 - bcc0, ecc1 - bcc1, ecc2 - bcc2

  let limit    = 100000
  // pi(x) ~= limit/(ln limit - 1)
  // Using pi(x) ~= limit/(ln limit - 2) to over-estimate
  let estimate = float limit / (log (float limit) - 1.0 - 1.0) |> round |> int

module Original =
  let primes limit =
    let ra = ResizeArray Common.estimate

    let mutable isPrime = true

    for i in 2 .. limit do
      for j in 2 .. i do
        if i <> j && i % j = 0 then
          isPrime <- false
      if isPrime then
          ra.Add i
      isPrime <- true

    ra.ToArray ()

module SolutionAaron =
  let primes limit =
    {2 .. limit}
    |> Seq.filter (fun i -> {2 .. i-1} |> Seq.forall (fun j -> i % j <> 0))
    |> Seq.toArray

module SolutionSteveJ =
  let primes limit =
    let ra = ResizeArray Common.estimate
    let mutable loop = true

    for i in 2 .. limit do
        let mutable j = 2
        while loop do
            if i <> j && i % j = 0 then
                loop <- false
            else
                j <- j + 1
                if j >= i then
                    ra.Add i
                    loop <- false
        loop <- true

    ra.ToArray ()

module SolutionDumetrulo1 =
  let rec isPrimeLoop (ra : ResizeArray<_>) i j limit =
    if i > limit then ra.ToArray ()
    elif j > i then
      ra.Add i
      isPrimeLoop ra (i + 1) 2 limit
    elif i <> j && i % j = 0 then
      isPrimeLoop ra (i + 1) 2 limit
    else
      isPrimeLoop ra i (j + 1) limit

  let primes limit =
    isPrimeLoop (ResizeArray Common.estimate) 2 2 limit

module SolutionDumetrulo2 =
  let rec isPrimeLoop (ra : ResizeArray<_>) i j limit =
    let incr x = if x = 2 then 3 else x + 2
    if i > limit then ra.ToArray ()
    elif j > i then
      ra.Add i
      isPrimeLoop ra (incr i) 2 limit
    elif i <> j && i % j = 0 then
      isPrimeLoop ra (incr i) 2 limit
    else
      isPrimeLoop ra i (incr j) limit

  let primes limit =
    isPrimeLoop (ResizeArray Common.estimate) 2 2 limit

module SolutionSimple =
  let rec isPrime i j k =
    if i < k then
      (j % i) <> 0 && isPrime (i + 2) j k
    else
      true

  let rec isPrimeLoop (ra : ResizeArray<_>) i limit =
    if i < limit then 
      if isPrime 3 i i then
        ra.Add i
      isPrimeLoop ra (i + 2) limit
    else
      ra.ToArray ()

  let primes limit =
    let ra = ResizeArray Common.estimate
    ra.Add 2
    isPrimeLoop ra 3 limit

module SolutionPushStream =
  type Receiver<'T> = 'T -> bool
  type PushStream<'T> = Receiver<'T> -> bool

  module Details =
    module Loops =
      let rec range e r i =
        if i <= e then
          if r i then
            range e r (i + 1)
          else
            false
        else
          true

  open Details

  let range s e : PushStream<int> =
    fun r -> Loops.range e r s

  let filter p (t : PushStream<'T>) : PushStream<'T> =
    fun r -> t (fun v -> if p v then r v else true)

  let forall p (t : PushStream<'T>) : bool =
    t p

  let toArray (t : PushStream<'T>) : _ [] =
    let ra = ResizeArray 16

    t (fun v -> ra.Add v; true) |> ignore

    ra.ToArray ()

  let primes limit =
    range 2 limit
    |> filter (fun i -> range 2 (i - 1) |> forall (fun j -> i % j <> 0))
    |> toArray

module SolutionUnstalling =
  let rec isPrime i j k =
    if i + 6 < k then
      (j % i) <> 0 && (j % (i + 2)) <> 0 && (j % (i + 4)) <> 0 && (j % (i + 6)) <> 0  && isPrime (i + 8) j k
    else
      true

  let rec isPrimeLoop (ra : ResizeArray<_>) i limit =
    if i < limit then 
      if isPrime 3 i i then
        ra.Add i
      isPrimeLoop ra (i + 2) limit
    else
      ra.ToArray ()

  let primes limit =
    let ra = ResizeArray Common.estimate
    ra.Add 2
    ra.Add 3
    ra.Add 5
    ra.Add 7
    ra.Add 11
    ra.Add 13
    ra.Add 17
    ra.Add 19
    ra.Add 23
    isPrimeLoop ra 29 limit

module SolutionVectors =
  open System.Numerics

  assert (Vector<int>.Count = 4)

  type I4 = Vector<int>

  let inline (%%) (i : I4) (j : I4) : I4 =
    i - (j * (i / j))

  let init : int [] = Array.zeroCreate 4

  let i4 v0 v1 v2 v3 =
    init.[0] <- v0
    init.[1] <- v1
    init.[2] <- v2
    init.[3] <- v3
    I4 init

  let i4_ (v0 : int) =
    I4 v0

  let zero    = I4.Zero
  let one     = I4.One 
  let two     = one + one
  let eight   = two*two*two

  let step = i4 3 5 7 9

  let rec isPrime (i : I4) (j : I4) k l =
    if l + 6 < k then
      Vector.EqualsAny (j %% i, zero) |> not && isPrime (i + eight) j k (l + 8)
    else
      true

  let rec isPrimeLoop (ra : ResizeArray<_>) i limit =
    if i < limit then 
      if isPrime step (i4_ i) i 3 then
        ra.Add i
      isPrimeLoop ra (i + 2) limit
    else
      ra.ToArray ()

  let primes limit =
    let ra = ResizeArray Common.estimate
    ra.Add 2
    ra.Add 3
    ra.Add 5
    ra.Add 7
    ra.Add 11
    ra.Add 13
    ra.Add 17
    ra.Add 19
    ra.Add 23
    isPrimeLoop ra 29 limit

module SolutionVectorsUnstalling =
  open System.Numerics

  assert (Vector<int>.Count = 4)

  type I4 = Vector<int>

  let init : int [] = Array.zeroCreate 4

  let i4 v0 v1 v2 v3 =
    init.[0] <- v0
    init.[1] <- v1
    init.[2] <- v2
    init.[3] <- v3
    I4 init

  let i4_ (v0 : int) =
    I4 v0

  let zero    = I4.Zero
  let one     = I4.One 
  let two     = one + one
  let eight   = two*two*two
  let sixteen = two*eight

  let step = i4 3 5 7 9

  let rec isPrime (i : I4) (j : I4) k l =
    if l + 14 < k then
      // i - (j * (i / j))      
      let i0 = i
      let i8 = i + eight
      let d0 = j / i0
      let d8 = j / i8
      let n0 = i0 * d0
      let n8 = i8 * d8
      let r0 = j - n0
      let r8 = j - n8
      Vector.EqualsAny (r0, zero) |> not && Vector.EqualsAny (r8, zero) |> not && isPrime (i + sixteen) j k (l + 16)
    else
      true

  let rec isPrimeLoop (ra : ResizeArray<_>) i limit =
    if i < limit then 
      if isPrime step (i4_ i) i 3 then
        ra.Add i
      isPrimeLoop ra (i + 2) limit
    else
      ra.ToArray ()

  let primes limit =
    let ra = ResizeArray Common.estimate
    ra.Add 2
    ra.Add 3
    ra.Add 5
    ra.Add 7
    ra.Add 11
    ra.Add 13
    ra.Add 17
    ra.Add 19
    ra.Add 23
    isPrimeLoop ra 29 limit

module SolutionBestAttempt =
  let rec isPrime i j k =
    if i < k then
      (j % i) <> 0 && isPrime (i + 2) j k
    else
      true

  let inline isqrt i = (i |> float |> sqrt) + 1. |> int

  let rec isPrimeLoop (ra : ResizeArray<_>) i limit =
    if i < limit then 
      if isPrime 3 i (isqrt i) then
        ra.Add i
      isPrimeLoop ra (i + 2) limit
    else
      ra.ToArray ()

  let primes limit =
    let ra = ResizeArray Common.estimate
    ra.Add 2
    isPrimeLoop ra 3 limit

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =

  let testCases =
    [|
      "Original"    , Original.primes
      "Aaron"       , SolutionAaron.primes
      "SteveJ"      , SolutionSteveJ.primes
      "Dumetrulo1"  , SolutionDumetrulo1.primes
      "Dumetrulo2"  , SolutionDumetrulo2.primes
      "Simple"            , SolutionSimple.primes
      "PushStream"        , SolutionPushStream.primes
      "Unstalling"        , SolutionUnstalling.primes
      "Vectors"           , SolutionVectors.primes
      "VectorsUnstalling" , SolutionVectors.primes
      "BestAttempt"       , SolutionBestAttempt.primes
    |]

  do
    // Warm-up
    printfn "Warm up"
    for _, a in testCases do
      for i = 0 to 100 do
        a 100 |> ignore

  do
    let init ()   = Common.limit

    let expected  = SolutionSimple.primes Common.limit

    for testCase, a in testCases do
      printfn "Running '%s' with %d (%d)..." testCase Common.limit Common.estimate
      let actual, time, cc0, cc1, cc2 = Common.time init a
      let result = if expected = actual then "GOOD" else "BAD"
      printfn "  ... it took %d ms with (%d, %d, %d) cc and produces %d %s primes" time cc0 cc1 cc2 actual.Length result 

  0
```

Comment: What CPU did you test on?  A Skylake gets more done per clock than an Atom, and in some cases you can have code A faster on one CPU, while code B is faster on another.

Comment: Is "unstalling" just an unroll with multiple accumulators?  And BTW, x86 SSE2 / AVX2 / AVX512 don't have integer division, only FP division.  So the vector-integer division you're using is itself emulated, maybe by unpacking to `double` for `divpd` unless the divisor is a compile-time constant.  (e.g. see [SSE integer division?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16822757) for int16 vectors using conversion `float` with C intrinsics.)  Compile-time-constant divisors can use the multiplicative-inverse trick.

Comment: Original F# code took 14533 ms, and original C# code took 1343 ms, when printing was removed. That's more in line with what I would expect given the disparity in amount of work done. I mentioned in my answer that I was surprised the F# code was *only* three times faster, and your benchmarks give me the explanation. The C# code was bottlenecked by printing to stdout, and when that bottleneck was removed, the `break`ing C# code ran about 11 times faster than the non-`break`ing F# code. That's more in line with what I would have expected. Great answer!

Answer (score 3):

If you want an iterative F# function completely equivalent to the for loops in C#, you can use the following tail-recursive function:

```
let rec isPrimeLoop i j limit =
    if i > limit then ()
    elif j > i then
        stdout.WriteLine (string i)
        isPrimeLoop (i + 1) 2 limit
    elif i <> j && i % j = 0 then
        isPrimeLoop (i + 1) 2 limit
    else
        isPrimeLoop i (j + 1) limit
```

As you can see, due to the way it calls itself, the `isPrime` flag is no longer needed. In place of the nested for loops, call it as follows:

```
let sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew ()
isPrimeLoop 2 2 100000
sw.Stop ()
printfn "Elapsed time: %ims" sw.ElapsedMilliseconds
```

PS: You can cut the time significantly by checking only the odd numbers after 2:

```
let rec isPrimeLoop i j limit =
    let incr x = if x = 2 then 3 else x + 2
    if i > limit then ()
    elif j > i then
        stdout.WriteLine (string i)
        isPrimeLoop (incr i) 2 limit
    elif i <> j && i % j = 0 then
        isPrimeLoop (incr i) 2 limit
    else
        isPrimeLoop i (incr j) limit
```