# Using a random long to generate random doubles

Tags: java, random

I'm implementing my own random number generator, and the algorithm I'm using naturally gives me a `nextLong()` method. However, using this core method, I need to implement the other standard methods, such as `nextLong(long)`, `nextInt()`, `nextDouble()`, and so on, in terms of `nextLong()`. For example:

```
public long nextLong(long n) {
    long bits, val;
    do {
        bits = (nextLong() << 1) >>> 1;
        val = bits % n;
    } while (bits - val + n - 1 < 0L);
    return val;
}

public int nextInt() {
    return (int)nextLong();
}
```

How can I implement `nextDouble`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know what the purpose of doing it yourself is, but you could just do it the same way the built-in `Random` class does it for [`nextDouble()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextDouble%28%29), as described in the javadoc:

> The method `nextDouble` is implemented by class `Random` as if by:
>
> ```
> public double nextDouble() {
>     return (((long)next(26) << 27) + next(27))
>       / (double)(1L << 53);
> }
> ```

Since you don't have an `int next(int bits)` method, but you do have a `nextLong()` method, use the fact that `((long)next(26) << 27) + next(27)` is equivalent to `next(53)`. It was done the long way because the `next(int)` method returns an `int`, i.e. max. 32 bits.

To get 53 bits from a long, you can use either the low or high 53 bits, your choice:

```
long low53 = nextLong() & ((1L << 53) - 1);
long high53 = nextLong() >>> (64 - 53);
```

So, your code would be:

```
private static final double DOUBLE_UNIT = 0x1.0p-53; // 1.0 / (1L << 53)
public double nextDouble() {
    return (nextLong() >>> (64 - 53)) * DOUBLE_UNIT;
}
```

The `DOUBLE_UNIT` stuff is how `Random` actually does it internally, because multiplication is faster than division, e.g. see [Floating point division vs floating point multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4125033/5221149).

Comment: The purpose of doing it myself is to implement a **reversible** random number generator, which implements a history and methods to step the state of the generator backwards and forwards. I investigated subclassing `Random` to do this, but it seemed like a hack to try to add all this functionality just by overriding `next`. Hence the separate class.

Comment: `((long)next(26) << 27) + next(27)` is logically the same as `next(53)`, except that the `next()` method in `Random` returns an `int`, i.e. max 32 bits. `next(53)` is the same as `nextLong() & ((1L << 53) - 1)` or `nextLong() >>> (64 - 53)`, depending on whether you want to low or high 53 bits of the long.