# Why is the conversion from BGR to LCh much slower than the reverse in this C++ program?

Tags: c++, image, image-processing, openmp, c++20

I wanted an efficient way to convert an image represented by a three dimensional array of float values between 0 and 1 to an LCh D65 array, as a programming challenge.

I know I can use OpenCV's cvtColor, but OpenCV operates on byte arrays, and I use floats because I implemented all separable [blend modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes), they all use float math, and cv2 only provides `cv2.COLOR_BGR2Lab`.

I have done a lot of researching, I have read the Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB), another Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIELAB_color_space), [GIMP source code](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp), [babl source code](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/babl)... And I computed the conversion matrix on my own, with native machine computed precision without rounding.

I have implemented it in Python at first, but I noticed that the conversion from BGR to LCh is over ten times slower than my other functions using the same looping function (basically I have a two level `numba.prange` nested loop that iterates over each pixel, and the conversion detail for each pixel is passed as an argument), so I implemented the same code in C++, still the same thing happens.

But, interestingly, the code that converts from LCh to BGR is almost as fast as the simpler conversions, I heard that the conversion from BGR to LCh is slow because it uses pow, however the reverse function also uses pow, in fact it does reversal of every operation done by the other function, yet it is much faster, how can this happen?

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <numbers>
#include <omp.h>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

using std::numbers::pi;

constexpr double one_third = 1.0 / 3.0;
constexpr double two_third = 2.0 / 3.0;

constexpr double D65_Xw = 0.9504559270516716;
constexpr double D65_Zw = 1.0890577507598784;

constexpr double D65_Xr = 0.4123835774573348;
constexpr double D65_Xg = 0.35758636076837935;
constexpr double D65_Xb = 0.18048598882595746;
constexpr double D65_Yr = 0.21264225112116675;
constexpr double D65_Yg = 0.7151677022795175;
constexpr double D65_Yb = 0.07219004659931565;
constexpr double D65_Zr = 0.019324834131038457;
constexpr double D65_Zg = 0.11918543851645445;
constexpr double D65_Zb = 0.9505474781123853;

constexpr double D65_Rx = 3.2410639132702483;
constexpr double D65_Ry = -1.5374434989773638;
constexpr double D65_Rz = -0.49863738352233855;
constexpr double D65_Gx = -0.9692888172936756;
constexpr double D65_Gy = 1.875993314670902;
constexpr double D65_Gz = 0.04157078604801982;
constexpr double D65_Bx = 0.05564381729909414;
constexpr double D65_By = -0.20396692403457678;
constexpr double D65_Bz = 1.0569503107394616;

constexpr double LAB_F0 = 216.0 / 24389.0;
constexpr double LAB_F1 = 841.0 / 108.0;
constexpr double LAB_F2 = 4.0 / 29.0;
constexpr double LAB_F4 = 1.0 / LAB_F1;
constexpr double LAB_F5 = 1.0 / 2.4;
constexpr double LAB_F6 = 0.04045 / 12.92;
constexpr double RtD = 180.0 / pi;
constexpr double DtR = pi / 180.0;
const double LAB_F3 = pow(LAB_F0, 1.0 / 3.0);

using std::tuple;
using std::vector;
using pixel = std::array<double, 3>;
struct image
{
    vector<pixel> data;
    int height;
    int width;
};
using std::chrono::steady_clock;
using std::chrono::duration;
using std::cout;
using std::function;

double min_d3(double a, double b, double c) {
    double m = a > b ? b : a;
    return m > c ? c : m;
}

double wrap(double d) {
    d = fmod(d, 1.0);
    return d < 0 ? d + 1.0 : d;
}

double wrap_deg(double r) {
    double d = fmod(r * RtD, 360.0);
    return d < 0 ? d + 360 : d;
}

void fill(pixel& p) {
    p[0] = double(rand()) / RAND_MAX;
    p[1] = double(rand()) / RAND_MAX;
    p[2] = double(rand()) / RAND_MAX;
}

image random_image(int height, int width) {
    srand(0);
    image image{ vector<pixel>(height * width), height, width };
    for (auto& l : image.data) {
        fill(l);
    }
    return image;
}

tuple<int, double, double> extrema(double a, double b, double c) {
    int i = 2;
    if (b > c) {
        std::swap(b, c);
        i = 1;
    }
    if (a > b) {
        std::swap(a, b);
    }
    if (b > c) {
        std::swap(b, c);
        i = 0;
    }
    return { i, a, c };
}

double hue(double b, double g, double r, double d, int i) {
    double h;
    switch (i)
    {
    case 2:
        h = (g - b) / (6 * d);
        break;
    case 1:
        h = one_third + (b - r) / (6 * d);
        break;
    default:
        h = two_third + (r - g) / (6 * d);
        break;
    }
    return wrap(h);
}

pixel HSL_pixel(double b, double g, double r) {
    auto [i, x, z] = extrema(b, g, r);
    double s = x + z;
    double d = z - x;
    double avg = s / 2;
    return d ? pixel{ hue(b, g, r, d, i), d / (1 - abs(s - 1)), avg } : pixel{ 0.0, 0.0, avg };
}

double gamma_expand(double c) {
    return c <= 0.04045 ? c / 12.92 : pow((c + 0.055) / 1.055, 2.4);
}

double LABF(double f) {
    return f >= LAB_F0 ? pow(f, one_third) : LAB_F1 * f + LAB_F2;
}

double LABINVF(double f) {
    return f >= LAB_F3 ? pow(f, 3) : LAB_F4 * (f - LAB_F2);
}

double gamma_contract(double n) {
    n = n <= LAB_F6 ? n * 12.92 : 1.055 * pow(n, LAB_F5) - 0.055;
    return n < 0 ? 0.0 : n > 1 ? 1.0 : n;
}

pixel BGR_to_LCh_D65(double b, double g, double r) {
    b = gamma_expand(b);
    g = gamma_expand(g);
    r = gamma_expand(r);
    double m, n, x, y, z;
    x = LABF((D65_Xr * r + D65_Xg * g + D65_Xb * b) / D65_Xw);
    y = LABF(D65_Yr * r + D65_Yg * g + D65_Yb * b);
    z = LABF((D65_Zr * r + D65_Zg * g + D65_Zb * b) / D65_Zw);
    m = 500 * (x - y);
    n = 200 * (y - z);
    return pixel{ 116 * y - 16, sqrt(m * m + n * n), wrap_deg(atan2(n, m)) };
}

void convert(const image& img, image& out, const function<pixel(double, double, double)>& mode) {
    size_t height, width;
    height = img.height;
    width = img.width;
    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            int64_t i = width * y + x;
            pixel px = img.data[i];
            out.data[i] = mode(px[0], px[1], px[2]);
        }
    }
}

pixel LCh_D65_to_BGR(double l, double c, double h) {
    h *= DtR;
    l = (l + 16) / 116;
    double b, g, m, r, x, y, z;
    x = D65_Xw * LABINVF(l + c * cos(h) / 500);
    y = LABINVF(l);
    z = D65_Zw * LABINVF(l - c * sin(h) / 200);
    r = D65_Rx * x + D65_Ry * y + D65_Rz * z;
    g = D65_Gx * x + D65_Gy * y + D65_Gz * z;
    b = D65_Bx * x + D65_By * y + D65_Bz * z;
    m = min_d3(r, g, b);
    if (m < 0) {
        r -= m;
        g -= m;
        b -= m;
    }
    return pixel{ gamma_contract(b), gamma_contract(g), gamma_contract(r) };
}

double timeit(const image& img, const function<pixel(double, double, double)>& mode, int runs = 256) {
    image out(vector<pixel>(img.width * img.height), img.height, img.width);
    auto start = steady_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < runs; i++) {
        convert(img, out, mode);
    }
    auto end = steady_clock::now();
    duration<double, std::nano> time = end - start;
    return time.count() / runs / 1000.0;
}

int main()
{
    image img = random_image(1080, 1920);
    double once = timeit(img, HSL_pixel);
    cout << "converting 1920x1080 BGR image to HSL vector: " + std::to_string(once) + " microseconds\n";
    once = timeit(img, BGR_to_LCh_D65, 16);
    cout << "converting 1920x1080 BGR image to LCh D65 vector: " + std::to_string(once) + " microseconds\n";
    image lch(vector<pixel>(1080 * 1920), 1080, 1920);
    convert(img, lch, BGR_to_LCh_D65);
    once = timeit(img, LCh_D65_to_BGR, 16);
    cout << "converting 1920x1080 BGR image from LCh D65 vector: " + std::to_string(once) + " microseconds\n";
}
```

```
PS C:\Users\Xeni> C:\Users\Xeni\source\repos\CIELCh\x64\Release\CIELCh.exe
converting 1920x1080 BGR image to HSL vector: 16679.885937 microseconds
converting 1920x1080 BGR image to LCh D65 vector: 212675.381250 microseconds
converting 1920x1080 BGR image from LCh D65 vector: 22048.650000 microseconds
```

Compiler flags:

```
/permissive- /ifcOutput "x64\Release\" /GS /GL /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /O2 /sdl /Fd"x64\Release\vc143.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "NDEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /std:c17 /Gd /Oi /MD /std:c++20 /FC /Fa"x64\Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64\Release\" /Ot /Fp"x64\Release\CIELCh.pch" /diagnostics:column
```

Extra flags:

```
/arch:AVX2 /fp:fast /openmp
```

I compiled using Visual Studio 2022.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Not sure about the origin of your problem, but just some thoughts on optimizing your code. 1. You are using quite some divisions by constants. As division is pretty expensive I would replace it by multiplication with the reciprocal value. 2. Try explicitely inlining heavily used functions, such as `gamma_contract`, `gamma_expand`, `LABF`, `LABINVF`, etc. I would not rely on the compiler to do that for you.

Comment: See also [Division vs. multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4125074/10192256)...

Comment: Top Hotspots
    Function Module CPU Time % of CPU Time
    pow ucrtbase.dll 9.376s 65.1%
    atan2 ucrtbase.dll 1.254s 8.7%
    [...]

Maybe this helps. Seems that it is indeed `pow`, however its conditional use seems imbalanced resulting in that large factor between the conversions.

Comment: It is much cheaper to compute `pow(x,3)` than `pow(x,1.0/3)`. The first one is just `x*x*x`, the other one is a complex algorithm. It’s probably also cheaper to do a `sin` and a `cos` call than an `atan2` call, but I’m less certain about that one.

Comment: Maybe I'm going blind, but I see no OpenMP pragmas in the code. In which case you could remove the /openmp compile flag. It's unlikely to make any big difference but might allow a few more optimisations.

Comment: @JimCownie There is an OpenMP pragma in the `convert` function, the main nested loop.

Comment: Ah, yes. Why "schedule(dynamic)"? There doesn't seem to be any obvious imbalance. (It probably won't make much difference, but should remove many unnecessary atomic operations).